# Why results of map() and list comprehension are different?

Tags: python, closures, list-comprehension, late-binding, generator-expression

The following test fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def f(*args):
    """
    >>> t = 1, -1
    >>> f(*map(lambda i: lambda: i, t))
    [1, -1]
    >>> f(*(lambda: i for i in t)) # -> [-1, -1]
    [1, -1]
    >>> f(*[lambda: i for i in t]) # -> [-1, -1]
    [1, -1]
    """
    alist = [a() for a in args]
    print(alist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest; doctest.testmod()
```

In other words:

```
>>> t = 1, -1
>>> args = []
>>> for i in t:
...   args.append(lambda: i)
...
>>> map(lambda a: a(), args)
[-1, -1]
>>> args = []
>>> for i in t:
...   args.append((lambda i: lambda: i)(i))
...
>>> map(lambda a: a(), args)
[1, -1]
>>> args = []
>>> for i in t:
...   args.append(lambda i=i: i)
...
>>> map(lambda a: a(), args)
[1, -1]
```

Comment: For those like me read the question but don't notice any problem at first: note the `[-1, -1]`!  Essentially `lambda i: ...` in a loop doesn't capture the current value of i.

Comment: related from Python FAQ: [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are different, because the value of `i` in both the generator expression and the list comp are evaluated lazily, i.e. when the anonymous functions are invoked in `f`.
By that time, `i` is bound to the last value if `t`, which is -1.

So basically, this is what the list comprehension does (likewise for the genexp):

```
x = []
i = 1 # 1. from t
x.append(lambda: i)
i = -1 # 2. from t
x.append(lambda: i)
```

Now the lambdas carry around a closure that references `i`, but `i` is bound to -1 in both cases, because that is the last value it was assigned to.

If you want to make sure that the lambda receives the current value of `i`, do

```
f(*[lambda u=i: u for i in t])
```

This way, you force the evaluation of `i` at the time the closure is created.

**Edit**: There is one difference between generator expressions and list comprehensions: the latter leak the loop variable into the surrounding scope.

Comment: Lambdas are evil because it isn't clear what what runtime context really is.

Comment: @S.Lott: Ordinary functions in Python are not that different. `def f(): return i` You don't know what `i` really is regardless function or lambda is considered.

Comment: In Python3, ["the loop control variables are no longer leaked into the surrounding scope."](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax)

Answer (score 6):

The lambda captures variables, not values, hence the code

```
lambda : i
```

will always return the value i is **currently** bound to in the closure.  By the time it gets called, this value has been set to -1.

To get what you want, you'll need to capture the actual binding at the time the lambda is created, by:

```
>>> f(*(lambda i=i: i for i in t)) # -> [-1, -1]
[1, -1]
>>> f(*[lambda i=i: i for i in t]) # -> [-1, -1]
[1, -1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Expression `f = lambda: i` is equivalent to:

```
def f():
    return i
```

Expression `g = lambda i=i: i` is equivalent to:

```
def g(i=i):
    return i
```

`i` is a [free variable](http://docs.python.org/ref/naming.html) in the first case and it is bound to the function parameter in the second case i.e., it is a local variable in that case. Values for default parameters are evaluated at the time of function definition.

Generator expression is the nearest enclosing scope (where `i` is defined) for `i` name in the `lambda` expression, therefore `i` is resolved in that block:

```
f(*(lambda: i for i in (1, -1)) # -> [-1, -1]
```

`i` is a local variable of the `lambda i: ...` block, therefore the object it refers to is defined in that block:

```
f(*map(lambda i: lambda: i, (1,-1))) # -> [1, -1]
```