# passing a dictionary by reference instead of using eval / how to pass a variable number of arguments

Tags: python, eval, pyramid

I was reading some questions about not to use exec or eval in python code.

I currently have a python web program based on pyramid and it takes some variables from a form and calls a function. All the argument of this function or optional, thus more or less what I do is

```
command = 'function_to_be_called ('

if optional_variable_in_form in request.params :
    command += 'optional_variable=optional_variable_in_form'

command += ')'

i = eval (command)
```

I am trying to enhance my application and I am trying to replace eval with something else. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided/1933703#1933703), where the author suggests to pass a dictionary by reference instead of using my solution.

So my questions are:

1. do you think it's a good way to go?
2. can I always pass a dictionary as proposed by the author to any function?
3. I find quite ofter the **, but I don't understand well what it does. Can you give me a hint about it or suggest a good page where I can study about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do:

```
function_to_be_called(**option_dict)
```

The old way to do this was with the [`apply`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/non-essential-built-in-funcs.html) function, but that has now been deprecated for the `*args`, and `**keywords` syntax.

This is actually really cool, since it means you can have a function and a tuple of arguments and call the function, so:

```
def polly(cracker, wants):
    if wants:
       print 'polly wants a', cracker
f = polly
t = ('cracker', True)
```

These are now all equivalent:

```
polly('cracker', True)
polly(*('cracker', True))
polly(*t)
f('cracker', True)
f(*t)
```

Now expand that for keyword arguments - but look  up a real tutorial. But as @Duncan points out, you can do this:

```
polly(**{cracker: 'cracker', wants: True})
d = {cracker: 'biscuit', wants: True}
polly(**d)
```

Comment: and more importantly for answering the actual question `d = { 'cracker': 'nut', 'wants': False}` `polly(**d)` is also equivalent.