# Getting syntax error with Python If statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing a small program to convert a string to an integer and then to binary within a list of strings. This is what I have

```
x=0
while x < len(list):
    list[x]=bin(eval(list[x])
    if(list[x].startswith("0b")):
        list[x]=list[x].replace("0b","")
```

I am getting a syntax error on the colon of the if statement, I'm not sure why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Your real problem is that you were missing a parens at the end of your `bin()` call.

```
x = 0
while x < len(list):
    list[x] = bin(eval(list[x]))
    if list[x].startswith("0b"):
        list[x] = list[x].replace("0b","")
```

You can remove the parens on your `if` line; python does not use parens around if test suites.

Better not to use built-in type names for variables, so `list` is a bad name for a variable. And if you want to strip off characters at the start of a string, you can use indexing:

```
list[x] = list[x][2:]
```

Presumably your code was not yet complete or you haven't discovered this yet due to the error, but your loop will never end as you are not incrementing `x`.

Last but not least: [do *not* use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided); it is a security hole waiting to happen.

Comment: And do not use variables named "list".

Comment: The first statement of this answer is a stylistic comment rather than the actual problem; nevertheless it is right. :)

Comment: The real problem is the missing `)` in the `bin` call .. rest is good and valuable advice, so perhaps that might be a better first line for the answer.