# Dynamic variable in Python

Tags: python, list, variables

How can I create lists with dynamic names in python, for example

```
for i in range(len(myself)):
   list(i) = []
```

what should I use instead of list(i) ?
it means that i want some names as below:

```
list1
list2
list3
...
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your objective. Can you please rephrase your question or elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes what exactly do you mean by "lists with dynamic names"?

Comment: [c for c in 'dynamic names']...sorry...couldn't help it

Comment: I have seen this question more than once on here and it usually ends with there being a better way to solve your problem... Like a dict

Answer (score 7):

I'd advise you to **just use a list or dictionary instead of dynamic variable names**. All the versions below  result in `lists[0]`, `lists[1]` etc being `[]`, which seems close enough to what you want, and will be more readable/maintainable in the long term. (Note: I'm using `lists` instead of `list` as a variable name because the latter would overwrite the builtin `list` function, which you probably don't want).

1) Version with `lists` being a list of lists (the numbers are just the order of the lists):

```
lists = [[] for i in range(len(myself))]
```

2) Same but with a for loop instead of a list comprehension:

```
lists = []
for i in range(len(myself)):
   lists.append([])
```

3) Version with `lists` being a dictionary of lists with numbers as keys (a bit more flexible if you want to remove some of the values later or such):

```
lists = {}
for i in range(len(myself)):
   lists[i] = []
```

**About dynamic variable names**, i.e. variables like `list1` instead of `lists[1]`...  Seriously, **you probably shouldn't do that**. It's unnecessarily complicated and hard to maintain. Think about it - next month you'll want to modify the script, and you'll try to figure out where the variable `list1` was defined, and you won't be able to do that with a plain text search. It's a pain.
But if you really want to for some reason, it's possible with `exec` - [here are some reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided) - or with modifying `locals()` - [bad idea according to documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals).  Also see comments for more discussion on why these things are a bad idea and how confusing it gets even talking about them.

Comment: This will do if you are interested :-)  `"list{} = []".format(i)` [I'm just transitioning to   `.format` from the old-style myself]

Comment: I would seriously consider removing that part about the dynamic variable with exec. Its a terrible idea and shouldnt even be made available as an option.

Comment: @jdi - it's a bad option, but consensual adults and all... I'm currently searching SO for good arguments against using it and will add links, if that helps.

Comment: Yea you should make sure to reinforce why its a terrible practice. Its kinda like saying "you shouldnt murder someone, but just in case you are curious, you could kill someone pretty easily using these outlined methods" ;)

Comment: What is funny is that if you google "why creating dynamic variables is bad" almost every summary snippet in the results contain "it is bad practice", for multiple languages

Comment: @jdi - hopefully the edited version contains enough reinforcement? Feel free to point me to better links explaining why it's bad.

Comment: @Levon - thanks! Added the new-style version to the answer. I really should learn that someday...

Comment: Instead of that nasty `exec` I'd rather use `locals()['list%d' % i] = []` - but of course not creating dynamic variable names is much better!

Comment: I removed the craziness about making dynamic variable names.  It's just silly, and an attractive nuisance.  Better to tell people the good way to do things.

Comment: @NedBatchelder - oops, I was editing at the same time you were and your edit got overwritten... I *did* give the good way to do things first, but I think more infomation is better than less (again, consenting adults etc). But go ahead and redo your edit if you think it's that bad.

Comment: With due respect to @ThiefMaster, changing `locals` in this way is specifically warned against in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) for `locals()`: "Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: @ThiefMaster - excellent point, I totally forgot about that. Changed. Thanks!

Comment: @DSM - Huh, I didn't know that... Yeah, dynamic variables really *are* a terrible idea either way. I ended up just putting a long note on why dynamic variables are bad, along with a short reference to `exec` and `locals` for completeness of information, with a link on why each is a bad idea. Hopefully that's a reasonable solution.

Comment: btw, an object refered as `lists[0]` already has a name: it is `'lists[0]'` itself. In a way it is literally a dynamic variable name.

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic variable names are very rarely a good idea; it is almost always better to use a dictionary:

```
myLists = {"list{}".format(i):[] for i in range(len_i)}
```

Do not use `list` as a variable name - it hides the existing keyword.