# How to automatically create x amount of variables in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I'm making a piece of code that asks users to input their name and three scores into a program. This will continue happening within a while loop until it is stopped (meaning there could be 2 users entering scores or 50 depending on how many are entered). I want to append the user's name and the three scores for each into a list (each user being a unique list) but I don't know how to automatically create different list names. For example, something like user1, user2, user3 etc. would do, as long as there was the same number of lists as users that entered their name and scores. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is a common question and the answer is: use a dictionary instead of plain variables.

Comment: Could you link me to the original question please?

Comment: There are many questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685199/how-to-create-an-unknown-amount-of-variables-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Also see the blogpost titled [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).