# How to create a list dynamically

Tags: python, list, dynamic

I'm struggling to understand how to create variable lists in python (I'm an R programmer).
I want to create a variable list name to store an array of minimum paths in a network with say 6 loads (sinks) and 3 generators (sources) using 'networkx', something like this:
`nx` is the network and `G` is a Digraph

```
for i in sinks:
    print("Analysis for node ",i," :")
    for j in sources:
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G,j,i):
            print (path)
            "node_"+str(i)[i] = path #How to do this??
```

in such a way that "node_1" has all paths from node 1 to all sources, "node_2" all paths from node 2 to all sources, etc.

Comment: Dynamic variables are considered a bad practice.  It would be better to store those values in a list/dictionary.

Comment: See [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) and [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and the answers on the 11 different SO questions linked from the second of those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963804/dynamic-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary:

```
for i in sinks:
    print("Analysis for node ",i," :")
    for j in sources:
        for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G,j,i):
            print (path)
            node[i][j] = path
```