# Creating new list names during iteration to .append() elements

Tags: python, pandas, list, iteration

> I am trying to create new list_names during an Iteration that I can
>   add Elements to.

```
# input
df = pd.DataFrame({"R1": [8,2,3], "R2": [-21,-24,4], "R3": [-9,46,6]})
```

[image: input]

```
# desired Output
list1 = df.values[0].tolist()
print(list1)
list2 = df.values[1].tolist()
print(list2)
list3 = df.values[2].tolist()
print(list3)
```

[image: desired output]

```
# failed attempt
for i in range(3):
    print(f'{"list"}{i}') = df.values[i].tolist()
```

[image: failed attempt]

Comment: No. Two issues: First, iteration on dataframes is an antipattern, and should be almost always avoided. Second, you're effectively asking how to make a dynamic number of variables on the fly. It's better to actually make a list/dict instead.

Comment: You're assigning a value to a function call, what does `f() = x` mean?

Comment: I am sorry to ask, but which function are you referring to?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: Don't try to create variables `list1`, `list2`, etc. Python (and other languages) has list and dictionary to keep many results - `result["1"] = ...`, `result["2"] = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work on the entire dataframe without iteration. Access the underlying array and convert it into a list of lists in one go.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"R1": [8,2,3], "R2": [-21,-24,4], "R3": [-9,46,6]})

#out = df.to_numpy().tolist() for pandas >0.24
out = df.values.tolist()
print(out)
print(out[0])
print(out[1])
print(out[2])
```

Output:

```
[[8, -21, -9], [2, -24, 46], [3, 4, 6]]
[8, -21, -9]
[2, -24, 46]
[3, 4, 6]
```

In this manner, you can use the `out` variable as a collection of all individual lists that you wanted.

---

If you wish to use a dictionary instead, you can also create that as follows:

```
out_dict = {f"list{i}":lst for i, lst in enumerate(out, start=1)}
#Output:
{'list1': [8, -21, -9], 'list2': [2, -24, 46], 'list3': [3, 4, 6]}

print(out_dict['list1'])
print(out_dict['list2'])
print(out_dict['list3'])
```

Between the list and dict approaches, you should be able to cover all use-cases you really need. It is generally a bad idea to try making a variable number of variables on the fly. [Related read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(3):
    print('list{} = {}'.format(i, df.loc[i].values.tolist()))
```

Output

```
list0 = [8, -21, -9]
list1 = [2, -24, 46]
list2 = [3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question, to dynamically create variables you can use [`exec()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/)

```
for i in range(3):
    exec("List%d=%s" % (i,df.values[i].tolist()))
print(List1)
```

**Secondly, above is a bad practise**. This poses a security risk when the values are provided by external data (user input, a file or anything). **So it's better avoid using it**.

You can always use [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) in that you can use `key` `value` pairs to achieve the same objective (See other answers).

Comment: Please do not recommend  bad programming practices, there's almost always a better way.

Comment: Yay! That one works very well for me :-) Can you please explain what you did?

Comment: @Paritosh Singh - What do you mean by that? Is it not recommended to do it this way?

Comment: @DieterMueller you have list and directory to keep many results. This is recomended way in Python and other languages.

Comment: @DieterMueller yeah, `exec` and `eval` are best avoided. further read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553641/python-is-exec-always-bad-practice-and-if-so-why-not-deprecated) and [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-evalexec-is-bad.html)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh this is the only way I know to create dynamic variables. That was the question right? Yeah, I mentioned it as bad practise. Is there any other safe way to dynamically create variables?  If yes, please do provide some examples.

Comment: The question was that. yes. But that is an XY problem. The answer should have been "please don't. Here's a cleaner way". Or if you really wish to showcase this, please highlight that this is *almost always a bad idea* in the answer itself

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thank you. I have updated the answer and highlighted as you suggested.