# Dictionary name from value stored in list/ tuple/ variable

Tags: python

I have a list as follows:

```
['ExampleName', ['1', 'some_value_1'], ['2', 'some_value_2']]
```

and I am trying to figure out how to write function or loop that takes the first element of the list and set it up as a dictionary name.
The desired output would be equivalent to:

```
ExampleName = {1:'some_value_1', 2:'some_value_2'}
```

So far tried `eval` command without success

Comment: If you have several such structures, you should rather build a dict like `{'ExampleName':  {1:'some_value_1', 2:'some_value_2'}, 'SomeOtherName': {....}, ...}`. Creating variables like you want to do is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't use dynamic variables, use another *container*, in this case, another `dict` probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in the comments it's a really bad idea to generate variable names based on other variable content, you should create a dictionary, something like this:

```py
example = ['ExampleName', ['1', 'some_value_1'], ['2', 'some_value_2']]

output = {
    example[0]: {element[0]: element[1] for element in example[1:]}
}
print(output)

>>> {'ExampleName': {'1': 'some_value_1', '2': 'some_value_2'}}
```

Comment: `dict(example[1:])` might be a neater way to construct the dictionary out of the list of pairs.

Comment: @kaya3 amazing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to do it like that. Using [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) may lead to some potential security risks.

Anyway, it does exactly what you're trying to achieve:

```
example_list = ['ExampleName', ['1', 'some_value_1'], ['2', 'some_value_2']]

name, *key_value_pairs = example_list
dictionary = {int(key): value for key, value in key_value_pairs}
exec(f"{name} = {dictionary}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9BCoMwEEX3OcXgJqa40e4KXXbbCxSRYEcaqkmIaVEkZ08nrVBxM/Df8N8wdvYPo48x4iQH22PTq9HDGW788gNXOSAvKJc0@WgGbN6yf2FT8jrhaocrXteMaWoVcHjivGIrlRvJuz3D7qr1ymjpZtosSvucCuIE3wp0xgHlYo1Kw04XGE7Y5l22pHMhOf7GkAnGrEvSzScixg8)

---

Also, see:

- [Python: Is exec always bad practice and if so why not deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553641/python-is-exec-always-bad-practice-and-if-so-why-not-deprecated)
- [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)
- [Be careful with exec and eval in Python](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/)

Comment: Indeed, looks exactly like what I'm trying to achieve in this case.

Comment: @User0261 if so, please mark this answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Note: this is not a good thing to do, just for fun.

You can create variables at runtime by using the `locals()` dictionary, for example:

```
>>> hello # this variable does not exist yet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    hello
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>> locals()['hello'] = 'world' # create new variable
>>> hello
'world'
>>> locals().pop('hello')  # delete variable
'world'
>>> hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    hello
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>>
```

Now by knowing this you should be able to build the dictionary you want

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450275/any-way-to-modify-locals-dictionary and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997184/why-is-it-bad-idea-to-modify-locals-in-python

Comment: No, `locals()` is exactly what you should'n't use even if you are trying to dynamically create variables, because assignment to `locals()` is not guaranteed to actually affect the local namespace. Indeed, in CPython, this will *only* work when `locals() is globals()`, i.e. when you are in the global namespace. It will fail inside a function, for example