# Extract (convert) variables and associated values from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ('x','y'), 'col2':(1,2)})
```

I want to extract variable and associated values, such as,

```
x=1
y=2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Hello. You can use _values_: `a.values`.

Comment: a.values or a.to_numpy will not help as I want two variables, x and y, to be created and their values get assigned.

Comment: It will give you the array of lists. You can extract everything from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exec` to parse and execute Python code written in a string.

As an example `exec('x=1')` will create and instantiate variable `x` that you can use later in your code.

With this in mind the following will work

```
s = ','.join(a['col1']) + '=' + ','.join(a['col2'].astype('str'))
exec(s)
print(x,y)
```

produces

```
1 2
```

Here `s` is given as a string `'x,y=1,2'`

If the values are say strings, you need to insert quote marks. Basically `s` needs to look like valid Python code. So for example you can do

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ('x','y'), 'col2':('red','green')})
s = ','.join(a['col1']) + '=' + ','.join(a['col2'].apply(lambda s:f'\'{s}\''))
exec(s)
print(x,y)
```

produces

```
red green
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works for me when the values are integer. What will be the modification when values are string, say, 'Red' and 'Green'?

Comment: @anix-anirban I added string example in the answer

Comment: @anix-anirban glad it helped! But do not overuse `exec`as it is generally considered bad practice, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553641/python-is-exec-always-bad-practice-and-if-so-why-not-deprecated#:~:text=As%20explained%20in%20other%20questions,issues%20and%20generally%20bad%20programming.). You can access those values in `df` using standard dtaframe methods so perhaps worth thinking about your design a bit more.