# How to use raw input to define a variable

Tags: python, variables, raw-input

Here is my code:

```
Adherent = "a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower."

word=raw_input("Enter a word: ")

print word
```

When I run this code and input Adherent, the word Adherent is produced. How can I have the definition of Adherent pop up instead?

Comment: You need `input` function.

Comment: @frostnational Not in Python 2.x, which is clearly what this is (due to the presence of `raw_input` and a `print` statement.

Comment: I suggest you try the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: @sweeneyrod [oh, right.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input)

Comment: @frostnational Yes, you don't want to call that function, as it evaluates the user input which you almost never want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can (should) use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) where words are mapped to definitions:

```
>>> word_dct = {"Adherent" : "a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower."}
>>> word=raw_input("Enter a word: ")
Enter a word: Adherent
>>> word_dct[word]
'a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower.'
>>>
```

Creating dynamic variables is a bad and potentially dangerous practice.  Not only is it very easy to lose track of them, but if you use `exec` or `eval` to create them, you run the risk of executing arbitrary code.  See [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided) for more information.  Even accessing `locals` or `globals` is generally frowned upon in favor of using a list or dictionary.

Comment: +1 What could be a better way to implement a ['dictionary'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary) than using a ['dictionary'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)?

Answer (score 1):

`Adherent` is a variable, and your first line sets the value to `"a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower."`
`word` is also a variable, the value being provided by the user.
`print()` prints the value that a variable stores. If you want the user to be able to select a word to define you'll need a dictionary of words.

```
words = {
  "Adherent": "a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower.",
}
```

The first value ("Adherent") is the key. It is associated with the second string.
A dictionary works like and list except in a list values are accessed by their index. In a dictionary values are accessed by their key.

So:

```
words = {
 "Adherent": "a person who follows or upholds a leader, cause, etc.; supporter; follower.",
}
word = raw_input("Word: ")
print words[word] #this is equivalent to words["Adherent"] if the user inputs "Adherent"
```

Just a sidenote, objects and variables generally should start with lowercase letters.