# How can I use a variable when calling a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

Basically, I have a lot of functions that have a similar name (`p1()`, `p2()`, `p3()`, `...`, `p20()`) and I don't want to call them all by hand. I want to do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
     p{i}()
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is there some other way to go around this?

Comment: You could do some crazy stuff with `globals()` to access objects/variables (functions are objects/variables) dynamically. Might be more sensible to create a data structure that contains your functions like a list or dict

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761. **TL;DR**: don't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799297/python-computing-a-function-name-from-another-function-name can help

Comment: Q: So what's the "relationship" between these (rather unimaginatively named) p1(), p2(), etc functions?  Q: Would it make sense to have a "collection" (e.g. an array or dictionary) of function pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2283243/421195?  Q: Would it make sense to wrap them all in a class, then invoke them collectively in a single class method?

Comment: Could you include some of these functions as part of the example?  Are they all very short?  Do you ever invoke them individually, or are they always invoked as a unit (and if so why are they separate functions in the first place)?

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be put into a list like any other object, so you can build a list of functions and then iterate over it:

```
p_funcs = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20]
for f in p_funcs:
    f()
```

Note that needing to do things like this might be an indication that your life would be easier if you refactored these functions into a smaller number of more complex functions.

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP named their functions so poorly, or if they're trying to do anything but save keystrokes with a poor design ... but this is a good solution.  To a questionable question ;)

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution is to create a mechanism where your functions are registered/stored so that they can be iterated over.

Here is a solution that uses a decorator to "register" each function and store them in a list so that they can be iterated over

```
registered_funcs = []


def register_func(f):
    registered_funcs.append(f)
    return f


@register_func
def p1():
    print('p1')


@register_func
def p2():
    print('p2')


for func in registered_funcs:
    func()
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is is based on `eval` cmd from [Computing a function name from another function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799297/computing-a-function-name-from-another-function-name).

```
def p1():
    print("testing function p1()")

def p2():
    print("testing function p2()")
    
for i in range(1, 3):
    eval('p' + str(i) + '()')
```

output

```
testing function p1()
testing function p2()
```

Comment: There are better alternatives than the (possible dangerous) eval function.

Comment: @Ruperto - this is really, really bad advice....

Comment: okay @paulsm4 i wish i knew why :)

Comment: Ruperto: Because using `eval()` (or `exec()`) is inherently a security hazard and can often be avoided.

Comment: is it safe enough to use eval() to call a function that we know is safe?