# Dictionary - 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to create a user interface with options to insert, delete and update data.  THe data will be manipulated in a text file.  I wanted to accept option from user and call respective function to do the activity.  One alternative that I found was to declare Dictionary 
The whole code is :

```
print("Select options from below")
dict_options = {'1' : 'Insert', 
                '2' : 'Update', 
                '3' : 'Delete',
                '4' : 'Display_number_of_records', 
                '5' : 'Display_all_records', 
                '6' : 'Exit'}



for key in dict_options.keys():
    value = dict_options.get(key)
    print(str(key) + ". " + value)


option = input("Enter an option : ")

while (option != '6'):
    value = dict_options.get(option)
    dict_options[option]()
option = input("Enter an option : ")


def Insert():
    print("Insert a record")
    return`enter code here`
```

When I execute, it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable at dict_options[option]()
```

Comment: The values in `dict_options` are strings, and are therefore not callable. What were you expecting to happen?!

Comment: Of course that will give an error as it's completely nonsensical. What are you even trying to achieve with that line?

Comment: You are calling strings not functions.

Answer (score 4):

Strings, such as `dict_options[option]`, are not callable, but functions are. Therefore, make the `dict_options` values be function objects:
Change

```
dict_options = {'1' : 'Insert', 
                '2' : 'Update', 
                '3' : 'Delete',
                '4' : 'Display_number_of_records', 
                '5' : 'Display_all_records', 
                '6' : 'Exit'}
```

to

```
dict_options = {'1' : Insert, 
                '2' : Update, 
                '3' : Delete,
                '4' : Display_number_of_records, 
                '5' : Display_all_records, 
                '6' : Exit}
```

Note you'll have to define the functions before defining `dict_options`.

---

Also, to print the *name* of the function, change `value` to `value.__name__`:

```
for key in dict_options.keys():
    value = dict_options.get(key)
    print(str(key) + ". " + value)
```

becomes

```
for key in dict_options.keys():
    value = dict_options.get(key)
    print(str(key) + ". " + value.__name__)
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Looks like unutbu beat me to it.

This line:

```
dict_options[option]()
```

Evaluates to something like this:

```
'Some String'()
```

You cannot call a string like this (try it!). You'll have to edit your dictionary so the values inside are functions (or some other kind of callable object), not strings.

EDIT:

Assuming the string values in your dictionary are the names of callable objects (e.g. functions), you COULD make it work the way you have it using `exec`:

```
exec(dict_options[option] + '()')
```

However, this is [BAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided) [BAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)! Do NOT do this!