# Why does this dict.get() throw this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code (probably self-explanatory):

```
def main():
    print("Please input 2 numbers to operate on: ")
    value1 = int(input())
    value2 = int(input())
    print("Please input an operator: ")
    operator = str(input())
    result ={
        '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
        '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
        '*': lambda x, y: x*y,
        '/': lambda x, y: x/y
        }.get(operator(value1, value2), "Error")
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I get the error:

```
Please input 2 numbers to operate on:
4
4
Please input an operator:
*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Megapoort\source\repos\Python switch function\Python_switch_function.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Megapoort\source\repos\Python switch function\Python_switch_function.py", line 13, in main
    }.get(operator(value1, value2), "Error")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I dont really understand what I did wrong here.

Comment: See [Dictionary - 'str' object is not callable \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742714/dictionary-str-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: `operator` is a string.  `operator(...)` is a function call.

Comment: Why are you calling `operator(value1, vaue2)`. Isn't `operator` a variable?

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the parenthesis in the wrong place- `.get(operator(value1, value2), "Error")` calls `operator` with `value1` and `value2`.

What you probably meant was `.get(operator, "Error")(value1, value2)` which correctly calls the results of the `.get` with the specified arguments.

Comment: And you'll *still* get the error if `get` can return `"Error"`.

Comment: I don't know if that's supposed to be a bad thing- if you give it a bad operator, it *does* return an error.

Comment: If you don't care about that error, they you probably wouldn't care enough to use `get` over simply risking a `KeyError` with `{...}[operator]`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a case where you should use `get`, as there isn't really a default function to use. If the user inputs an undefined operator, you *should* raise an exception (just not necessarily a `KeyError`) or exit.

```
def main():
    print("Please input 2 numbers to operate on: ")
    value1 = int(input())
    value2 = int(input())
    print("Please input an operator: ")
    operator = str(input())
    try:
        op = {
        '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
        '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
        '*': lambda x, y: x*y,
        '/': lambda x, y: x/y
        }[operator]
    except KeyError:
        sys.exit(f"Invalid operator {operator}")

    result = op(value1, value2)
    print(result)
```

If you *were* to use `get`, it should also return a function. For example,

```
result = {...}.get(operator, lambda x, y: None)(value1, value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to want you want to achieve. It might help if you split the result assignment statement in separate steps:

First, make a mapping between the operator symbol (a `str`) and the lambda, fully equal to your example:

```py
    operator_map = {
        '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
        '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
        '*': lambda x, y: x*y,
        '/': lambda x, y: x/y,
    }
```

Next, get the lambda (a function object) your operator symbol maps to, and let the interpreter generate an exception if an unknown operator was entered:

```py
    func = operator_map[operator]
```

Next, call the function with the two operands you have read earlier:

```py
    result = func(value1, value2)
```

If you would really like to combine it all in one statement:

```py
    result = {
        '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
        '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
        '*': lambda x, y: x*y,
        '/': lambda x, y: x/y,
    }[operator](value1, value2)
```

**Tip:**
The lambda expressions you provided are already provided in the standard library [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). `lambda x, y: x+y` is equivalent to `operator.add`, `x-y` --> `operator.sub`, `x*y` --> `operator.mul`, and the `x/y` lambda is equivalent to `operator.truediv`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator = str(input())` is one value a string.
But later you want 2 values from it: `operator(value1, value2)` also operator is at that moment a string not a function so there is no way operator() will yield any results beside an error.

Fix it like this:

```
print("Please input 2 numbers to operate on: ")
value1 = 1
value2 = 2
print("Please input an operator: ")
operator = str("+")
result ={
    '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
    '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
    '*': lambda x, y: x*y,
    '/': lambda x, y: x/y
    }.get(operator, "Error")
print(result(value1, value2))
```

Comment: You haven't *used* the function returned by `get`.

Comment: Note that this would still throw the same error if I entered, say "5" for `operator`, so using `get` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
result ={
    '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
    '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
    '*': lambda x, y: x*y,
    '/': lambda x, y: x/y
    }.get(operator(value1, value2), "Error")
```

You are doing too many things in a single statement. Break it into smaller pieces:

```
operations = {
    '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
    '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
    '*': lambda x, y: x*y,
    '/': lambda x, y: x/y
}
foo = operator(value1, value2)
result = operations.get(foo, "Error")
```

Now we can see that `operator(value1, value2)` is causing the error because the value of `operator` is a string and we can't use parentheses after a string. Instead, we need parentheses after a function. And the function is in the dictionary that you can look up with a string:

```
operation = operations.get(operator)
result = operation(value1, value2)
```

The moral of the story is to break up a complex statement into smaller pieces so that you can reason about each little step rather than getting mixed up about one large step.

Comment: But `None` is not a callable value.

Comment: @chepner No it's not.

Comment: Then you need to adjust your use of `operations.get`, because it can return `None`.

Comment: @chepner This solves the problem in the OP where valid input raises an error. How to handle invalid input is a separate issue, which you address. The purpose of my answer is to explain a strategy for solving the problem that can be applied in more than just this specific situation.