# How can I parse a dictionary string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to convert a string to a dictionary with `dict` function, like this

```
import json
p = "{'id':'12589456'}"
d = dict(p)
print d['id']
```

But I get the following error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Why does it fail? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you have is a string, but `dict` function can only iterate over tuples (key-value pairs) to construct a dictionary. See the examples given in the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)'s documentation.

In this particular case, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the string to the corresponding `dict` object, like this

```
>>> p = "{'id':'12589456'}"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> d = literal_eval(p)
>>> d['id']
'12589456'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `p` is a string containing JSON (ish), you have to load it first to get back a Python dictionary. Then you can access items within it:

```
p = '{"id":"12589456"}'
d = json.loads(p)
print d["id"]
```

However, note that the value in `p` is not actually JSON; JSON demands (and the Python `json` module enforces) that strings are quoted with double-quotes, not single quotes. I've updated it in my example here, but depending on where you got your example from, you might have more to do.

Comment: Basically you solved a different problem and recommend that to OP?

Comment: `p is a string containing JSON (ish)` - No it is not.

Comment: @LalitSingh `json.loads` will not work for you. It will work only with JSON strings. What you have is not a JSON string.

Comment: what is difference between "{'id':'12589456'}"   and   '{"id":"12589456"}'

Comment: @LalitSingh JSON keys can have only double quotes. Single quotes are not valid JSON.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes always throw error  when i use json.loads()

Comment: @LalitSingh You should use `ast.literal_eval` like I have shown in my answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye if i use eval() then what will be the problem

Comment: @LalitSingh If you know what you are doing then you can use `eval`, but it is usually considered bad. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/1903116) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/1903116)