# How to create a dictionary from user input as name in python?

Tags: dictionary

Suppose user enters `hello`

I want to create empty dictionary `hello = {}` which will be later used as required.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the dictionary to be called hello, or that you want the input from the user (which in this case is hello) to be added to a dictionary?

Comment: Possibly `exec("input= {}") where input is "hello" (not tried).

Comment: I want the dictionary to be called hello

Comment: why did i even get -3 on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a dictionary whose name is input by the user, you can use something like this:

```
while True:
    dictName = raw_input('Name: ') # use input on Python 3
    if not dictName:
        break

    globals()[dictName] = {}

print test1
print test2
```

The code above will ask for a name and inject a new dict into `globals`, so you can reference that later in the code (ie. print it). [It doesn't use `eval`, which is unsafe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Example usage:

```
Name: test1
Name: test2
Name:
{}
{}
```