# Passing string as an argument for plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like this function to take a string, indicating which data(x, y or z) it should plot, as an argument.

```
def plotfit(axis):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
    ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, func_z(vars,fitted_z),c='r')
    ax.set_title('B_z of %s' % name)
    ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, zfield, c='b')
```

How do I make the bolded parts of the code below replaced by my string argument so that, e.g. plotfit(x) would replace all instances of bolded z below with "x" and plot accordingly ? 
Points of interest:

- func_**z**
- fitted_**z**
- **z**field
- 'B_**z** of %s'

What I imagine would be something along the lines of:

```
ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, func(axis as a string)(vars,fitted_(axis as a string)),c='r')
```

Comment: `def plotfit()` doesn't take any input arguments. Can you please elaborate a little bit more on what exactly it is you want to do? Do you want to add arguments to it?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include some examples of how your are hoping to call this function?

Comment: Editted for more clarity, hopefully.

Comment: @joo I think my solution solves the issue, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#exec) to execute different code depending on the `string` type argument I presume you want to parse to the function, for example:

```
def plotfit(axis):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
    exec("ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, func_" + axis + "(vars,fitted_" + axis + "),c='r')")
```

A similar technique can be used for the other lines you want to do this on.

Please bear in mind that it is not recommended to use `exec` (or `eval`) as it can often hide bugs and can be ambiguous. See: [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Comment: Worked as expected, thank you. I am not allowed to edit your post, there is one missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: The end should look like this:  c='r')")

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary that will act as a switch statement in your code as outlined below.

```
def plotfit(a_letter):
    assert a_letter in ["x", "y", "z"]
    fitted = {"x" : fitted_x, "y" : fitted_y, "z" : fitted_z}
    fields = {"x" : field_x, "y" : field_y, "z" : field_z}
    afunc = {"x" : afunc_x, "y" : afunc_y, "z" : afunc_z}
    # ...
    ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, afunc[a_letter](vars,fitted[a_letter]),c='r')
    #...
    ax.set_title('B_%s of %s' %(a_letter, name))
```

However, you could also consider the alternatives:

- Have plotfit to take the functions fitted, func, field as argument
- Have plotfit to take an object as argument that would have the fitted ,func and field methods
- Have plotfit defined in a base class and uses self.func, self.fit and self.field. Those methods would be implemented in different subclasses

Note that using exec statement for such a case is seen as bad practice as described in [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)