# Concatenating variable names in Python

Tags: python, concatenation

I need to check variables looking like this:

```
if name1 != "":
    (do something)
```

Where the number right after "name" is incremented between 1 and 10.

Do I need to write the test ten times or is there a way (without using an array or a dict) to "concatenate", so to speak, variable names?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    if "name" + str(i) != "":
        (do something)
```

Edit: I can't use a list because I'm actually trying to parse results from a Flask WTF form, where results are retrieved like this:

```
print(form.name1.data)
print(form.name2.data)
print(form.name3.data)
etc.
```

Comment: You use a list to hold your values, not ten different variables!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a list or a dict for this? It would be the most straightforward solution

Comment: @Rodolphe You should explain _why_ you can't use a list. This just sounds like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In almost all cases, using `eval` to do something like this means you have a terrible software design issue.

Comment: In the **specific case** where there are **already existing** attributes of an object like `form.name1`, `form.name2` etc. **and** you can't modify the code (e.g. to make `form.name` be a list of those values), the appropriate tool is `getattr`. I have added an appropriate duplicate. In general, use a list or dictionary to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use a list, such as:

   ```
   names = ['bob', 'alice', 'john']
   ```

   And then iterate on the list:

   ```
   for n in names:
     if n != "":
        (do something)
   ```
2. or you could have a compounded if statement:

   ```
   if (name1 != "" or name2 != "" or name3 != "")
   ```

The best solution would be to use solution #1.

Comment: I can't use a list unfortunately... but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use a list or a dict, you could use `eval`

```
for i in range(10):
    if eval("name" + str(i)) != "":
        (do something)
```

Comment: Few notes 1. [Is Using eval In Python A Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940) 2. [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451) 3. [Ned Batchelder: Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: [**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your app have invalid logic. You should use list, dict or your custom obj.

You can get all variable in globals. Globals is a dict.

You can do next:

```
for i in range(10):
    if globals().get('name%d' % i):
        # do something
```