# How to get list of strings from list-like string that includes nan?

Tags: python, string, list, abstract-syntax-tree

Here is toy-example, I've string like this:

```
import numpy as np
z = str([np.nan, "ab", "abc"])
```

**Printed** it looks like `"[nan, 'ab', 'abc']"` but I've to process `z = str([np.nan, "ab", "abc"])`

I want to get from `z` list of strings excluding nan:

```
zz = ["ab", "abc"]
```

**To be clear**: `z` is input (string, that look list-like), `zz` is wanted output (list)

There is no problem if `z` doesn't contain nan, in such `ast.literal_eval(z)`  do the job, but with nan I get error about malformed node or string.

**Note:** `np.nan` doesn't have to be first.

Comment: The title of your question says "includes nan" but the body of your question says "excluding nan".  Is your question how to filter a list removing all NaN values?

Comment: Hi, I've mean that input string contains "nan" but output list doesn't contain it

Comment: What characters can the inner strings contain?

Comment: Why are you *building* the example string that way? Is the actual string built that way as well? Could you remove nans *before* building the string?

Comment: @KellyBundy this is simplified example, I've obtain such strings when I read csv file from pandas that contained lists of strings in the column

Comment: @QuantChristo I'm not familiar with pandas, but perhaps you could fix that process? Sounds like the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @KellyBundy I misread that bit, now the question is why do they have a string...

Comment: do you expect to have substrings like `"abc nan, def"` in your original string?

Comment: @mozway I don't expect to have nan substrings but I can't exclude such case

Comment: @KellyBundy Unfortunately I don't have control how those csv files were created but I need to parse them

Comment: How does the line in the csv file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
eval(z,{'nan':'nan'}) # if you can tolerate then: 
[i for i in eval(z,{'nan':'nan'}) if i != 'nan']
```

It may have security considerations.

Comment: This is perfectly fine :)

Comment: No, `eval` is rarely "perfectly fine"

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, your goal is to parse csv or similar.

If you want a trade-off solution that should work in most cases, you can use a regex to get rid of the "nan". It will fail on the strings that contain the substring `nan,` (with comma), but this seems to be a reasonably unlikely edge case. Worth to explode with you real data.

```
z = str([np.nan, "ab", np.nan, "nan,", "abc", "x nan , y", "x nan y"])

import re
literal_eval(re.sub(r'\bnan\s*,\s*', '', z))
```

output: `['ab', '', 'abc', 'x y', 'x nan y']`

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` is suggested over `eval` exactly because it allows a very limited set of statements. As stated in the docs: "Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The **string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures**: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis." `np.nan` is none of those so it cannot be evaluated.
There are few choices to handle this.

- Remove `nan` by operating on the string before doing evaluation on it. Might be problematic if you want to avoid also removing nan from inside the actual strings.
- **NOT ADVISED - SECURITY RISKS** - standard `eval` can handle this if you define nan variable in the namespace
- And finally, I think the best choice but also hardest to implement: like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295414/something-like-ast-literal-eval-to-execute-variable-assignments), you take the source code for `ast`, subclass it and reimplement `literal_eval` in such a way that it knows how to handle `nan` string on it's own.

Answer (score -2):

Use filter() function:

```
list(filter(lambda f: type(f)==str, z))
```

Answer (score -3):

Many Solutions one of these is

```
z = [nan, 'string', 'another_one']
string_list = []

for item in z :
    # find the object come from str Class and Append it to the list
    if item.__class__ == str:
            string_list.append(item)
```

Comment: This is not a solution to my problem.  input `z` is string not list.

Comment: Okay I will Update it