# Finding the Area of a Triangle using if else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to write a program that prompts the user for the lengths of three sides of a triangle, determines that the three lengths can form a triangle and if so uses Heron's formula to compute the area to 4 digits of precision.This is what I have so far I don't know where or how to put in the math

```
import math
def main():
    print()
    print("Triangle Area Program")
    print()
    a, b, c = eval(input("Enter three lengths separated by commas: "))
    print()
    s = (a+b+c) / 2.0
    area = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    if a > c:
        a, c = c, a
    if b > c:
        b, c = c, b
    else:
        a + b > c
        print("A triangle cannot be formed.")

main()
```

Comment: use `math.sqrt`

Comment: `math.sqrt` is what you need

Comment: Instead of using `eval` on that line, you could use `a,b,c = map(float, input('...').split(','))`

Comment: this is what is supposed to happen                                                                     "Triangle Area Program"                                                                                     Enter three lengths separated by commas: 3, 7, 9                                            Area of the triangle = 8.7856 square units                                                           mine says a triangle cannot be formed

Comment: The else is only attached to `if b > c:`. Also you are never outputting your calculated area in any form

Comment: so how do i attach the other parts and how do i output my calculated area

Comment: In the else clause, the `a + b > c` instruction does nothing. I suppose you meant `if a+b > c`

Comment: Ok, so your question is really why you don't compute the area? Your function doesn't return anything, and `a + b > c` doesn't make much sense  since I think that will just evaluate to a `bool`. Also, do you intend to evaluate every `if`? I think you mean to use `elif` because otherwise every operation interferes with the next.

Comment: @MattPoretsky sorry to sound condescending, but if you have to ask that question you need to find a good python tutorial and learn the basics. Chaining `if - elif - else` and using `return` are absolute basics of any programming language and should not have to be asked on SO

Comment: yeah so i am still completely lost and confused i'm not sure what to change and when i do change what you are telling me nothing is working

Comment: As @UnholySheep has stated, the reason that what we're saying won't make a lot of sense is that there are a number of issues with the code. It would take some time to fix all of them, and you'd be leapfrogging a lot of steps in understanding several core aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly modified version of your program that checks if the inputs are compatible in one compound conditional expression and replaces the use of `eval`:

```
import math

def main():
    print("\nTriangle Area Program\n")
    a, b, c = map(float, input("Enter three lengths separated by commas: ").split(','))

    if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
        s = (a + b + c) / 2.0
        area = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
        return round(area, 4) # round area to four decimal places
    else:
        raise ValueError("The inputs you entered cannot form a triangle")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

More on avoiding `eval` when you can [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Comment: this does not work after i enter the numbers a blank line comes after it

Comment: This works but under the numbers it says "none" how do i get rid of that and how can i make the number limited to 4 digits

Comment: @MattPoretsky As per `None`, I have a feeling you have `print(area)` instead of `return area` :)

Comment: i see that however i need it to say "Area of the triangle = ,area, "square units." how do you suggest i do this. thanks

Comment: You can do that with the `print` function. Replace `print(main())` with `print("Area of the triangle = ", main(), "square units.")`

Comment: last question when i do this it only works correctly for 3,7,9 and 1,2,5. when i enter any other numbers all it does is print the numbers and not the "Area of the triangle = square units.

Comment: import math

def main():
    print("Triangle Area Program")
    print()
    a, b, c = map(float, input("Enter three lengths separated by commas: ").split(','))

    if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
        s = (a + b + c) / 2.0
        area = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
        print()
        return round(area, 4) 
                
    else:
         print()
         print("A triangle cannot be formed.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Area of the triangle =", main(), "square units.")

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible version of your mathy problem:

```
import math


def heron(a, b, c):
    return 0.25 * math.sqrt((a + (b + c)) * (c - (a - b)) * (c + (a - b)) * (a + (b - c)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print()
    print("Triangle Area Program")
    print()
    print()

    try:
        description = "Enter three lengths separated by commas: "
        sides = sorted(map(float, input(description).split(',')))

        if (sides[1] + sides[2]) < sides[0]:
            print("A triangle cannot be formed.")
        else:
            a, b, c = sides
            print("Area of triangle {0}-{1}-{2} is {3:.4f}".format(
                sides[0], sides[1], sides[2], heron(a, b, c)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Check your input!!!")
        print("--> Error: {0}".format(e))
```

Few notes about this version:

- It's parsing your floating-point input values and sorting at the same time, that way you can check directly whether a triangle can be formed or not
- It's not using the naive heron formula, instead is using another one which is [numerically stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

I've decided to give you another version because in the comments you'll find some good advices about yours

Comment: this comes up with an error message after entering the numbers

Comment: @MattPoretsky I've added some control error checks, you need to enter your input following this format `a,b,c`, that is , a string which contains three float numbers separated by commas

Comment: @MattPoretsky This version is already printing the area with 4 decimal digits, look at `{3:.4f}`