# Generic Pythonic Code to Solve: 2**2**2**2**0

Tags: python, generics, python-3.5

[image]

I got the python code below that solves the expression above. I believe there should be a more generic Pythonic approach. By generic I mean it should solve any combinations of numbers (not just: 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 0) e.g: 3 ** 2 ** 4 ** 1 ** 0, 3 ** 3 ** 1 ** 2 ** 0 etc

```
def get_expo(expo, index, cur_expo):
    return int(expo[index-1]) ** cur_expo


def solve_expo(expo):
    expo = expo.split("^")
    index = len(expo) - 1
    cur_expo = int(expo[-1])
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(expo)):
        if index == 1:
            result = get_expo(expo, index, cur_expo)
            return "Answer is: " + str(result)
        else:
            cur_expo = get_expo(expo, index, cur_expo)
            index -= 1



print solve_expo("2^2^2^2^0")
```

I need a better pythonic approach to solving it?

Comment: What makes you think that code won't work for other numbers?

Comment: What's wrong with using **? It works with all numbers.

Comment: Why do you have that print statement at the end of your code?

Comment: I feel it should the code length should be shorter than that and probably there is a built-in function to doing it? Generally I feel a more pythonic way is available by experienced python programmers?

Comment: @sawreals2 As I read the question, he is asking for a more elegant "pythonic" solution even though this code does work.

Comment: `eval` comes to mind but, isn't there better than `eval("2**2**2**2**0")` to do this? I mean we know `eval` is evil right?

Comment: that is true @ sabbahillel

Comment: which makes it off topic for SO. go post on codereview.SE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Comment: I think that doing the split and passing the list into the recursive function is a little nicer as I show below.

Comment: Added an answer with the use of `reduce()`. Please note one should always avoid the usage of `eval` and `exec` in the code due to security concerns. Mentioning this because most voted answer is based on the usage of `eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach to achieve this by using [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function as:

```
>>> operation_str = '3^2^4^1^0'
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: int(y)**int(x), operation_str.split('^')[::-1])
43046721
```

Explanation based on step by step operation:

```
>>> operation_str.split('^')
['3', '2', '4', '1', '0'] # Converted str into list
>>> operation_str.split('^')[::-1]
['0', '1', '4', '2', '3'] # Reversed list
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: int(y)**int(x), operation_str.split('^')[::-1])
43046721  # Check reduce() fucntion linked above to know how it works
```

Also read: [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Comment: Thanks, this is a more professional code

Answer (score 2):

Python's built-in `**` operator respects precedence correctly already. You can feed it the full expression and get the answers you are expecting.

```
>>> 3 ** 2 ** 4 ** 1 ** 0
43046721
```

So the straightforward (but potentially dangerous) way to write your function is something like this, by just evaluating the expression after replacing the `^` with `**`:

```
def solve_expo(expression):
    return eval(expression.replace('^', '**'))
```

---

[Obviously, `eval` might not be suitable for your situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/2069350) (or you might just want to do something a little more interesting), so you could rewrite your solution as a recursive one. It's a little more elegant, at any rate.

```
def solve_expo(expression):
    base, exp = expression.split('^', 1)  # Split off just the first ^
    if '^' in exp:
        return int(base) ** solve_expo(exp)  # More exponents later, so resolve them and raise our base to that power
    return int(base) ** int(exp)  # base and exp are plain numbers, so just return base^exp
```

Comment: it runs as script not on the cmd prompt

Comment: @UmarYusuf Anything you do on the interactive interpreter you can do as a script.

Comment: Ok, let me study it

Comment: eval is evil, but you can assert that the original code has only digits and `^`. i guess that would make it safe.

Comment: I split it into a list and just had the recursive function work on the integers

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to handle it as a recursion, this code seems to handle it nicely. The split creates a single list of string values which are then handled completely within the recursive function.

```
val = '2^3^4^5^6^7'
vals = val.split('^')

def solve_expo(expo):
    if len(expo) == 1:
        return int(expo)
    else:
        return solve_expo(expo[:-1]) ** int(expo[-1])

solv_expo(vals)
```