# forcing a program to calculate an input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, raw-input

I was wondering if I could force the program to calculate an input before converting it to an integer.
for example my code is

```
    shift=int(raw_input("input the shift you want "))
```

If I was to input 4**2 which should then in theory equal 16 however as the raw input is a string this cannot happen.
I would like to know if there was force the program to calculate the input meaning if I inputted a calculation then the program would work it out instead of just converting it to an integer and causing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind being terribly unsafe, you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval), which accepts a single string argument as input, and executes it as Python code:

```
shift = eval(raw_input("input the shift you want "))
```

[And here is an explanation of why you shouldn't do this in any kind of production code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1933481/2615940).

A better option is to actually build a proper parser to behave like a calculator. There are plenty of resources for this floating around SO and elsewhere online.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look