# Why is exec() command running with no errors but not producing the expected output?

Tags: python, exec

I'm creating a very basic python program that allows a user to enter a command that is then ran as code.

For example I have imported a file called textScripts.py: within that file there is a function called `createFile()`. When the user enters `textScripts.createFile()` it is passed into `exec()`. It runs without error and exits the program but the file isn't created!

I know the `createFile()` function works because if I put `textScripts.createFile()` in the code it creates a file.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
commandList=[]
while(commandRun):
    count = 0
    commandList.append(input(">>>"))
    exec(commandList[count])
    print(commandList[count])
    count += 1
```

[here is a screenshot of the code being run:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMS7m.png)

```
>>> textScripts.createFile()
>>>
```

[here is a screenshot of the folder:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9J97.png)

```
__pyCache__
textScripts.py
CLIFile.py
```

there should be a file in this folder

here is the function `createFile()`:

```
def createFile(
    destination = os.path.dirname(__file__),
    text = "Sick With the Python\n"
    ):
    ''' createFile(destination, text)

        This script creates a text file at the
        Specified location with a name based on date
    '''
    date = t.localtime(t.time())
    name = "%d_%d_%d.txt" %(date[1], date[2], date[0])

    if not(os.path.isfile(destination + name)):
        f = open(destination + name, "w")
        f.write( text )
        f.close
    else:
        print("file already exists")
```

I apologize in advance if this is an obvious questions; I'm new to python and have been looking for hours for an answer as to why this happens.

Comment: Can you copy what the screenshot said and the folder structure to the question instead of linking to them? The screenshot is impossible to read and it would be nice to have the information in the question.

Comment: Also mention what you are passing with `input()`, without that how can someone help you?

Comment: @EliSadoff yes I can

Comment: Try to avoid `exec()` and `eval()`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided) for more info.

Comment: @jojo is there a better way to do this without exec and eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save file to wrong folder (you can insert "print(destination + name)" in your function)

You need to replace this:

```
destination + name
```

to this:

```
os.path.join(destination, name)
```

PS:

1. You don't close the file (f.close -> f.close())
2. The best way to open any resource is using "with".

For example:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('line')
```