# How to create variables with their name taken as input from user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to take an input string from user in python3 . for example : abc is an input string . Now i want to create a dictionary insider my program with "abc" name.Is it possible?

Comment: of course, what is troubling you? What will the value for that name be?

Comment: it will be the input given during runtime

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and I didn't found this question when I googled. Can you plz unmark this post as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very much possible, but I don't recommend trying to do it. If you really need what your asking for, something like this would work:

```
>>> exec(input("Enter name: ") + ' = {}')
Enter name: myDict
>>> myDict
{}
>>> locals()['myDict']
{}
>>>
```

However it is generally [A bad idea to use `exec()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided) especially with a combination of `input()`. There is usually a better way to do something without it. In fact, **there is a better way of doing it.**

Instead of trying to create variables based upon user input, use a dictionary instead. This way, you have good control over your "variables". You could easily extend this to add more than one "variable" from user input to your variable dictionary:

```
>>> varDict = {}
>>> name = input("Enter name: ")
Enter name: myDict
>>> varDict[name] = {}
>>> varDict[name]
{}
```

You can dynamically create variables using a while loop, and `input()`. Create a dictionary to hold all your user inputted variables. Create a while loop, then ask the user for a variable name and value:

```
>>> varDict = {}
>>> while True:
        name = input("Enter a variable name: ")
        value = input("Enter a variable value: ")
        varDict[name] = value


Enter a variable name: var1
Enter a variable value: a
Enter a variable name: var2
Enter a variable value: b
Enter a variable name: var3
Enter a variable value: c
Enter a variable name: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 2, in <module>
    name = input("Enter a variable name: ")
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> varDict
{'var1': 'a', 'var2': 'b', 'var3': 'c'}
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually , i have to create a compiler like program in python for college assignment for which we have not been taught anything in the lecture. So to easily implement a struct like feature , i was trying if this dynamic naming is possible , so that my work could get a little bit easier.   Can you suggest any less complex method to implement a structure like feature. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also , i was thinking that even if i create a dictionary with input name then how i would be able to access the dictionary in my further program

Comment: @helptaker The closes your gonna get to seamless dynamic naming is using a dictionary. And really, this isn't to complex of a method. I'll add some more to my answer to help clear your confusion though.

Comment: @helptaker Your welcome. And see if what I've added to my answer helps.