# How do I create a stata local macro in python?

Tags: python, stata

Let me edit my question to clarify.  Here is the python code:

```
decade_begin = 1970

while decade_begin <= 1994:
    for x in range(0, 10):
        a= decade_begin + x
    decade_begin = a+1
    decade_end=a

print "year_",decade_begin,"s" #start year
```

The output of the last line is:

```
year_1980s
year_1990s
```

I want to be able to create a variable such that:

```
year_1990s = [a]
```

In stata this is quite easy, using a local macro `x'.  But in python I think mixing string and int in a variable name is not allowed.

```
forval i = 1979/1994 {
whatever if year == `i' 
save year_`i'.dta, replace
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement in python?

Comment: For those familiar with Python, but not with STATA, could you explain what `x' does? Do you mean something like [format literals](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1019/string-formatting/4021/format-literals#t=201611212058243848285)?

Comment: I think it is called a local macro in STATA. The simplest explanation I found is here: https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/stata_prog1.htm

Comment: It **is** called a local macro. That is quite explicit at source http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?foreach But I doubt that knowing Stata [NB] terminology helps answer the python question, which is a question of how to loop over a list.

Comment: Still not sure whether this question is about [string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1019/string-formatting#t=201611212151031953559) or ["variable variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/1639625) (but probably not about loops or file access).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is a rough equivalent:

```
for x in ["apple", "banana", "orange"]:
    with open(x + ".data", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write("whatever")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to create a variable name using a string to name the variable. (The equivalent of local macros in Stata are called variables in Python). You can do this using the `exec` function:

```
>>> for i in range(1979, 1995):
...    exec("name_" + str(i) + " = " + str(i))

>>> print(name_1994)
1994
```

This code assumes you're using Python 3. If you're using Python 2, remove the outer parentheses for the lines with `exec` and `print`.

Using `exec` is not the best way to approach this problem in Python, however (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1933481/1133952)). You will likely run into problems later on if you try to code in Python the same way you're used to coding in Stata.

A better approach might be to create a dictionary and use a different key for each number. For example:

```
>>> names = {}
>>> for i in range(1979, 1995):
...    names[i] = i
>>> print(names)
{1979: 1979, 1980: 1980, 1981: 1981, 1982: 1982, 1983: 1983, 1984: 1984, 1985: 1985, 1986: 1986, 1987: 1987, 1988: 1988, 1989: 1989, 1990: 1990, 1991: 1991, 1992: 1992, 1993: 1993, 1994: 1994}
```