# Equivalent of Stata macros in Python

Tags: python, pandas, stata, statsmodels, stata-macros

I am trying to use Python for statistical analysis.

In Stata I can define local macros and expand them as necessary:

```
program define reg2
    syntax varlist(min=1 max=1), indepvars(string) results(string)
    if "`results'" == "y" {
        reg `varlist' `indepvars'
    }
    if "`results'" == "n" {
        qui reg `varlist' `indepvars'
    }
end

sysuse auto, clear
```

So instead of:

```
reg2 mpg, indepvars("weight foreign price") results("y")
```

I could do:

```
local options , indepvars(weight foreign price) results(y) 
reg2 mpg `options'
```

Or even:

```
local vars weight foreign price
local options , indepvars(`vars') results(y) 
reg2 mpg `options'
```

Macros in Stata help me write clean scripts, without repeating code.

In Python I tried string interpolation but this does not work in functions.

For example:

```
def reg2(depvar, indepvars, results):
    print(depvar)
    print(indepvars)
    print(results)
```

The following runs fine:

```
reg2('mpg', 'weight foreign price', 'y')
```

However, both of these fail:

```
regargs = 'mpg', 'weight foreign price', 'y'
reg2(regargs)

regargs = 'depvar=mpg, covariates=weight foreign price, results=y'
reg2(regargs)
```

I found a similar question but it doesn't answer my question:

- [How do I create a stata local macro in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729173/how-do-i-create-a-stata-local-macro-in-python)

There is also another question about this for R:

- [How do I create a "macro" for regressors in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615693/how-do-i-create-a-macro-for-regressors-in-r)

However, I could not find anything for Python specifically.

I was wondering if there is anything in Python that is similar to Stata's macros?

Comment: String macros in Stata are a little eccentric from the outside. Stata like many other languages is based on an eclectic borrowing from previous languages plus some original ideas. In this case the inspiration was, if I understand correctly, a mix of C and Unix shell programming.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how i can achieve something similar in python?

Comment: See my answer. Sorry it took that long.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions, I have now changed the accepted answer to yours. I will definitely look into Pyexpander, I ended up using a list as you also suggest here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want the `*` and `**` operators for calling functions:

```
regargs = 'mpg', 'weight foreign price', 'y'
reg2(*regargs)
```

Use `*` to expand a list or tuple into positional arguments, or use `**` to expand a dictionary into keyword arguments to a function that requires them.

For your keyword example, you need to change the declaration a little bit:

```
regargs = dict(depvar='mpg', covariates='weight foreign price', results='y')
reg2(**regargs)
```