# Python: How to use ast.literal_eval() for sets in set?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Sets are not hashable as they are mutable. But is there a way to still use literal_eval on {1, 2, {3, 4}}? I just want to know that the outer structure is a set, I don't care about the inner type, but sets within sets are possible inputs.

**Update:**

The input is read from a file as string.

Comment: Is `{1, 2, {3, 4}}` stored as a string? (If yes, then you can't)

Comment: Trying on the latest stable Python3.6: `{1, 2, {3, 4}}` is not a malformed string and is an acceptable input, but sets are still non-hashable, `frozensets` might be the way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hack `ast.literal_eval` to make it return a frozenset when it sees a set. Here is how to do:

- search where the library for your Python installation is
- it contains the file `ast.py` that contains the function `literal_eval`
- copy that function (using a different name) in you own module and change it to import all the relevant names from the `ast` module
- in the line processing a `Set`, replace the generation of a `set` with a `frozenset`

You can then use it to safely parse literal sets containing sets. For my Python 3.5, I used:

```
def frozen_literal_eval(node_or_string):
    """
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts,
    sets, booleans, and None.

    SPECIAL: This version uses frozensets instead of sets
    """
    # SPECIAL: import names from ast module
    from ast import parse, Expression, Str, Bytes, Num, Tuple, List, Set, Dict
    from ast import NameConstant, UnaryOp, UAdd, USub, BinOp, Add, Sub
    # END SPECIAL
    if isinstance(node_or_string, str):
        node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
    if isinstance(node_or_string, Expression):
        node_or_string = node_or_string.body
    def _convert(node):
        if isinstance(node, (Str, Bytes)):
            return node.s
        elif isinstance(node, Num):
            return node.n
        elif isinstance(node, Tuple):
            return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, List):
            return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, Set):
            #SPECIAL: returns a frozenset
            return frozenset(map(_convert, node.elts))
            # END SPECIAL
        elif isinstance(node, Dict):
            return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
                        in zip(node.keys, node.values))
        elif isinstance(node, NameConstant):
            return node.value
        elif isinstance(node, UnaryOp) and \
             isinstance(node.op, (UAdd, USub)) and \
             isinstance(node.operand, (Num, UnaryOp, BinOp)):
            operand = _convert(node.operand)
            if isinstance(node.op, UAdd):
                return + operand
            else:
                return - operand
        elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and \
             isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)) and \
             isinstance(node.right, (Num, UnaryOp, BinOp)) and \
             isinstance(node.left, (Num, UnaryOp, BinOp)):
            left = _convert(node.left)
            right = _convert(node.right)
            if isinstance(node.op, Add):
                return left + right
            else:
                return left - right
        raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
    return _convert(node_or_string)
```

I could the use:

```
>>> s = '{ 1, 2, {3, 4}}'
>>> frozen_literal_eval(s)
frozenset({1, 2, frozenset({3, 4})})
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to work around a bit more, but it works. 

The next problem I have are lists in sets. It gives me "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'", but lists in lists work fine, so why is it a problem now that lists are not hashable either? Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

*Answer to Question 1*:

> Are sets within sets are possible input?

You may use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) to create a nested set object:

> Return a new set or frozenset object whose elements are taken from iterable. The elements of a set must be hashable. To represent sets of sets, the inner sets must be frozenset objects. If iterable is not specified, a new empty set is returned.

For example:

```
>>> frozen_set = frozenset({3, 4})

>>> my_set = {1, 2, frozen_set}
>>> my_set
{frozenset({3, 4}), 2, 1}
```

*Answer to Question 2*:

> Is there a way to still use literal_eval on {1, 2, {3, 4}}?

No, there is no way as there is no `ast.literal_eval` for `frozenset` iterable. There was a [proposal](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-January/011798.html) in 2008 by *Raymond Hettinger* for `frozenset` literal. Guido even pronounced his [agreement](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-January/011814.html) but then changed his mind. Check [this mail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-February/019225.html) for more insights.

But you may use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) instead as:

```
>>> my_str = '{frozenset({3, 4}), 2, 1}'

>>> eval(my_str)
{1, 2, frozenset({3, 4})}
```

Before using `eval`, please also read: [Why should `exec()` and `eval()` be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Comment: The input is read from a file as string and the file contains a lot of strings. Also they can be nested again and again and again, I would have to edit all of the strings first... I guess that's not very practical. But thank you for your answer!