# Executing Python multi-line statements from command-line, while inside python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I've got thousands of small multi-line python3 programs to run, which are generated as strings. They all have a similar structure, and end with a `print` command. Here's some simple examples

```
prog_1 = 'h=9\nh=h+6\nprint(h)'
prog_2 = 'h=8\nh-=2\nprint(h)'
prog_3 = 'c=7\nc=c+4\nprint(c)'
```

They should all be executable if you were to run them from the interpreter. What I mean is, they look like small normal programs when you print them,

```
>>> print(prog_1)
h=9
h=h+6
print(h)


>>> print(prog_2)
h=8
h-=2
print(h)


>>> print(prog_3)
c=7
c=c+4
print(c)
```

I want to execute them from inside my program, (which generates them), and capture the output, (i.e. the output of the `print`) as a variable, but I'm stuck how to do it?

Something like

```
import os
output = os.popen("python -c " +  prog_1).read()
```

would be great but I get this error?

```
/bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I think the problem is I don't know how to execute the small programs from the command line? This line executes, but does not print out??

```
python -c "'h=9\nh=h+6\nprint(h)'"
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to execute them in a **separate process** then you can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
>>> prog_1 = 'h=9\nh=h+6\nprint(h)'
>>> result = subprocess.run(["python"], input=prog_1, encoding="utf-8", stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
>>> print(result)
15
```

Note that Python 3.6 is required for `encoding` support, and Python 3.5 is required for `subprocess.run`.

In Python 3.5, you need to pass the input as `bytes`, and the returned output will also be bytes.

```
>>> result = subprocess.run(["python"], input=bytes(prog_1, "utf-8"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
>>> print(str(result, "utf-8"))
15
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot :))) That's nearly it, I just need to convert to integer, `output=int(result)`. Do I have to somehow shut down/kill the `subprocess`? I've got to run about `100k`, of these little things, on multiple cores?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to command line you can use:

```
exec(prog_1)
```

**Warning**: `exec()` can be very dangerous - [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot, I never new that. I need to somehow capture the output though, so for example, `output = exec(prog_1)`, doesn't seem to work ??? It's empty, not `15`?

Comment: I look forward to evaluating a program involving `shutil.rmtree("/")`.

Comment: Also be aware that `exec` will pollute the namespace of your program meaning your little mini programs could easily clobber and kill your main one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec`:

```
>>> prog_1 = 'h=9\nh=h+6\nprint(h)'
>>> exec(prog_1)
15
```