# Indent rules in verbatim strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I'm trying to copy-paste and run python code which basically looks like this:

```
mycode = """
    def f():
        print("f called")

    f()
"""

eval(mycode)
```

And getting error

```
  File "<string>", line 2
    def f():
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

If I change indent like

```
mycode = """
def f():
    print("f called")

f()
"""
```

Then I'm getting error

```
  File "<string>", line 2
    def f():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it a broken code I'm trying to run, or I can fix this somehow?
Original code is supposed to be runnable "as is", without any modifications.

I tried this in IPython 3.6.0

Comment: you can `eval` expressions. Not function definitions.

Comment: Your first code snipped it just wrongly indented; for the 2nd one could use `exec(mycode)` but what is your *actual* aim? Almost certainly this is the wrong way to solve it

Comment: I forgot to add call to f(). See my corrected code

Comment: As @Chris_Rands already said: [avoid `eval()` and `exec()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Comment: Why are you doing this?  It is almost certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define a function in an `eval`, which is for expressions.

Use `exec`:

```
>>> mycode = """
... def f():
...   print("f called")
...
... f()
... """
>>> exec(mycode)
f called
```

Comment: Yep, for me as well. Still not getting why calling f() does not turn statement into expression

Comment: @TOPKEK Why would it turn it into an expression? The function definition is already not an expression. Adding more things to that is not going to somehow turn it into an expression.

Comment: Function definition can be a part of expression, no?

Comment: No. Expressions must be rvalues, in other words, anything you could use on the right side of an assignment operator (`value = expression`). You can use _lambda_ expressions.