# Creating multiple dataframes with a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

This undoubtedly reflects lack of knowledge on my part, but I can't find anything online to help. I am very new to programming. I want to load 6 csvs and do a few things to them before combining them later. The following code iterates over each file but only creates one dataframe, called `df`.

```
files = ('data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv', 'data4.csv', 'data5.csv', 'data6.csv')
dfs = ('df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6')
for df, file in zip(dfs, files):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    print(df.shape)
    print(df.dtypes)
    print(list(df))
```

Comment: I think you create 6 dataframes, but keep only the last one.  Correct?  df gets overwritten in each iteration.   BTW. are there a couple of quotes missing on the second line?

Comment: Quotes missing on the first line too.   Your code doesn't even pass a syntax check, let alone that it would create a single dataframe.

Comment: Thanks. The quotes are there in my local code. I was just sloppy in abbreviating it for the post.

Comment: You can store them in a list and then later concatenate the dataframes i.e. Before `for` loop, `ls = []`, last line in for loop `ls.append(df)`, and then after for loop `pd.concat(ls)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you think your code is doing something that it is not actually doing.

Specifically, this line: `df = pd.read_csv(file)`

You might think that in each iteration through the `for` loop this line is being executed and modified with `df` being replaced with a string in `dfs` and `file` being replaced with a filename in `files`. While the latter is true, the former is not.

Each iteration through the `for` loop is reading a csv file and storing it in the variable `df` effectively overwriting the csv file that was read in during the previous `for` loop. In other words, `df` in your `for` loop is not being replaced with the variable names you defined in `dfs`.

**The key takeaway here is that strings (e.g., `'df1'`, `'df2'`, etc.) cannot be substituted and used as variable names when executing code.**

One way to achieve the result you want is store each csv file read by `pd.read_csv()` in a dictionary, where the key is name of the dataframe (e.g., `'df1'`, `'df2'`, etc.) and value is the dataframe returned by `pd.read_csv()`.

```
list_of_dfs = {}
for df, file in zip(dfs, files):
    list_of_dfs[df] = pd.read_csv(file)
    print(list_of_dfs[df].shape)
    print(list_of_dfs[df].dtypes)
    print(list(list_of_dfs[df]))
```

You can then reference each of your dataframes like this:

```
print(list_of_dfs['df1'])
print(list_of_dfs['df2'])
```

You can learn more about dictionaries here:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: So very true! :)

Comment: I thought I read you can use strings as variable names, but you shouldn't do it.

Comment: You are right. You can use them as variable names but the manner in which you do so makes your code harder to understand. Specifically, you could write: `eval(s + "=1")` and, if `s` is a string that conforms to Python's variable naming conventions, this code would assign 1 to the variable with the name stored in `s`. There's a good post about why you shouldn't use `eval` here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided.

Comment: Is it possible to reference each of the dataframes by using df1 instead of list_of_dfs['df1'] ?

Comment: @KeithDowd This works quite good, but I was asking myself how to name the dataframes df1, df2,... instead of list_of_dfs['df1']. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Use dictionary to store you DataFrames and access them by name

```
files = ('data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv', 'data4.csv', 'data5.csv', 'data6.csv')
dfs_names = ('df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6')
dfs ={}
for dfn,file in zip(dfs_names, files):
    dfs[dfn] = pd.read_csv(file)
    print(dfs[dfn].shape)
    print(dfs[dfn].dtypes)
print(dfs['df3'])
```

Use list to store you DataFrames and access them by index

```
files = ('data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv', 'data4.csv', 'data5.csv', 'data6.csv')
dfs = []
for file in  files:
    dfs.append( pd.read_csv(file))
    print(dfs[len(dfs)-1].shape)
    print(dfs[len(dfs)-1].dtypes)
print (dfs[2])
```

Do not store intermediate DataFrame, just process them and add to resulting DataFrame.

```
files = ('data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv', 'data4.csv', 'data5.csv', 'data6.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in  files:
    df_n =  pd.read_csv(file)
    print(df_n.shape)
    print(df_n.dtypes)
    # do you want to do
    df = df.append(df_n)
print (df)
```

If you will process them differently, then you do not need a general structure to store them. Do it simply independent.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
def do_general_stuff(d): #here we do common things with DataFrame
    print(d.shape,d.dtypes)

df1 = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")
# do you want to with df1

do_general_stuff(df1)
df = df.append(df1)
del df1

df2 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv")
# do you want to with df2

do_general_stuff(df2)
df = df.append(df2)
del df2

df3 = pd.read_csv("data3.csv")
# do you want to with df3

do_general_stuff(df3)
df = df.append(df3)
del df3

# ... and so on
```

And one geeky way, but don't ask how it works:)

```
from collections import namedtuple
files = ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv', 'data4.csv', 'data5.csv', 'data6.csv']

df = namedtuple('Cdfs',
                ['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6']
               )(*[pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])

for df_n in df._fields:
    print(getattr(df, df_n).shape,getattr(df, df_n).dtypes)

print(df.df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can store them too

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

files = ('doms_stats201610051.csv', 'doms_stats201610052.csv')
dfsdic = {}
dfs = ('df1', 'df2')
for df, file in zip(dfs, files):
  dfsdic[df] = pd.read_csv(file)
  print(dfsdic[df].shape)
  print(dfsdic[df].dtypes)
  print(list(dfsdic[df]))

print(dfsdic['df1'].shape)
print(dfsdic['df2'].shape)
```