# EOL error, where is the mistake?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eol

I'm trying to get pyton execute this, but it keeps showing EOL err, where is the mistake in here?

```
exec("a = \"def f(s):\n try:\n  exec(s)\n except: Exception\n print('Error')\"\nb = \"while True: f(input(''))\"\nexec(a)\nexec(b)")
```

This code is result of me trying to merge these two exec lines into 1, maybe there is better way to do it, there are those two exec lines:

```
exec("def f(s):\n try:\n  exec(s)\n except: Exception\n print('Error')")
exec("while True: f(input(''))")
```

Comment: If this kind of things is necessary, it's probably better to build the AST up piece-by-piece rather than exec it as a whole string.

Comment: Why does this need to be `exec`ed and not hard-coded? Programs should **never** execute inputted code, simple typos can cause catastrophic results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do [smells horrible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided), Python-wise. But technically you have a multi-line string literal in your code, and it must be enclosed in triple quotation marks:

```
exec("a = '''def f(s):\n try:\n  exec(s)\n except: Exception\n print('Error')'''\nb = \"while True: f(input(''))\"\nexec(a)\nexec(b)")
```

There are some other errors in your code withing the string.