# how to execute function in txt file

Tags: python

I have a function

```
def output5() :
    print("OK")
def output5() :
    print("no")
def output5() :
    print("yes")
```

So If I make code like this

```
 output5()
 output6() 
 output7()
```

it will say
ok
no
yes

And I have a file output.txt and there are messages follow:

```
output5() 
output6() 
output7()
```

I wanted to implement a function in python like:

```
a=open('output.txt').readlines()
a
```

so that ok no yes would be printed

but it only says:

```
'output5()\n', 'output6()\n', 'output7()\n'
```

not ok no yes

how can I execute functions included in txt file?

Comment: could you be more specific on what you want please

Comment: Do you have these output6, output7 functions defined in some `.py` file ?

Comment: If these are function names, where are the function bodies defined?

Comment: Text files don't contain functions. They contain strings. You would need to parse those strings.

Comment: sorry guys I've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Using `exec` or `execfile` is generally considered bad practice and possibly unsafe ([Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)). While it is the answer to your question, you should probably use another solution.

If I interpret the question correctly, you could do one of these, depending on your python version:

- Python 2: you can use `execfile('output.txt')`
- Python 3: `exec(open('output.txt').read())`

Note that this is not the usual way to do things in python. You should probably use a module (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), unless you have strong reasons not to.

Comment: My hypothesis is that `output.txt` contains a list of functions to be called, and that these functions are already defined in the steering script (the one "reading" `output.txt`). But I can be wrong.

Comment: Another issue is that python3 seems to have dropped execfile()

Comment: @frankpaek I'm still confused. If I had to guess again what you want to do, I would give the same answer.

Comment: it says NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined

Comment: I have output1 to output10 txt files, they include certain senteces.
and I've made the code to arrange them in permutation order.
so in def output() , it would be like output1() output3() output7() output4() like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! You're awesome
and sorry for my English skill and poor python skill :(
I really appreciate it !!! Have a good day :D

Comment: This might be good for OP's use-case, but it might be good to give the customary warning about the security dangers of things like `eval()` and `exce()`.  Is OP 100% sure that these text files will never contain malicious code?

Comment: @JohnColeman Added. How is it worth than importing and using a module though? One still needs to be 100% sure that these module never contain malicious code.