# How to create a list from a string inside another list. Python?

Tags: python

I was thinking is there a way to take a string that is in a list and convert it to list in python? For example, I have a list: `teams = ['team_one', team_two', team_three,]`. How do I get three separate empty lists from it?
`team_one = []`
`team_two = []`
`team_three = []`
Thank you!

Comment: Don't. Use a dictionary instead:`dic = { k: [] for k in teams}`

Comment: I invoke [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why do you need your end user to supply the names of variables *internal* to your program?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about dynamically creating variables. Ideally you should not be doing this and use typical data structures instead.

If you had to you could do something like this

```
    for name in teams:
        globals()[name] = 0

    for i in range(10):
        globals()['variable{}'.format(i)] = 0
```

For more information as to why this is a bad idea check out [this](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) link

below is a slightly easier to understand code but also still a bad idea.

```
>>> name = input("Enter a variable name: ")
Enter a variable name: X
>>> globals()[name] = 42
>>> X
42
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea in common ways, but if forced, you can do:

```
>>> teams = ['team_one', 'team_two', 'team_three']
>>> for i in teams:
...     exec(i + ' = []')
... 
>>> team_one
[]
>>> team_two
[]
>>> team_three
[]
```

Comment: Thank you! @Naufan Rusyda Faikar. Why this is a bad idea?

Comment: There are several articles that have explained about it, including [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/8791891) and what has been explained by @josh-zwiebel.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a for loop to add to a dictionary (or create a dictionary with list comprehension, as @Blotosmetek commented). Both do the same thing.

```
d = {}

for item in teams:
    d[item] = []
```

EDIT:

In hindsight, a for loop can just be used to create the variables with no need for a dictionary.

```
for item in teams:
    item = []
```