# Python | Read Script In Website And Run In Terminal

Tags: python

How to read python script in a website and run it in terminal ?

Example:

Script In pastebin.com:

```
import time
print('Hello World')
time.sleep(2)
exit()
```

Script In Terminal :

```
import requests
link = "https://pastebin.com/raw/script"
r = requests.get(link)
#Now How Run Script From Website ?
```

Please help me :)

Comment: You'd need to `eval` it, but that's an exceedingly bad idea…

Answer (score 0):

The exec built-in function might be a way to execute the script with text.

```
import requests
link = "https://pastebin.com/raw/script"
r = requests.get(link)

#run the script
exec(r.text)
```

[EDIT] This method is unsafe and not recommanded.
See this post: [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Answer (score 0):

Now you have the response in your code as r,
and you want to first retrieve the text of the response:

```
response_text = r.text
```

Optionally, reset the encoding of the response text:

```
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

Now execute the content of the response with the Python built in exec method:

```
exec(response_text)
```