# Creating Lists from CSV files Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings. I now want to create a list for each string within my original list. I don't want to hard code in the new lists.

For example if my list is my_list = ['Paul', 'Ringo', 'John', 'George'] I want to create 4 new lists, one for each string (Paul = [ ] Ringo = [ ] etc).
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Create a dictionary whose keys are the band members' names and whose corresponding values are the lists of attributes associated with each band member.

Comment: You can use exec updated the answer

Comment: @codian I know it's been a while, but please, let us know if any of answers below have what you needed. If so, please accept the one you prefer to "close the question". Hope it has helped!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically name variables on run time with Python. However, you could fill a dictionary where the keys are the items from the list and the values are an empty list. Like this:

```
my_list = ['Paul', 'Ringo', 'John', 'George']
my_dict = {}

for name in my_list:
    my_dict[name] = []

print(my_dict)
# {'Paul': [], 'Ringo': [], 'John': [], 'George': []}
```

For bonus, you can use dictionary comprehension which is way shorter. Like this:

```
my_list = ['Paul', 'Ringo', 'John', 'George']
my_dict = {item:[] for item in my_list}

print(my_dict)
# {'Paul': [], 'Ringo': [], 'John': [], 'George': []}
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, please accept any answer that is correct for you which will help others in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a case to use a dictionary:

```
my_list = ['Paul', 'Ringo', 'John', 'George']

dict = {}

for beatles in my_list:
    dict[beatles] = []

print(dict)

dict['Paul'].append('Yellow Submarine')

print(dict['Paul'])
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

```
   my_list = ['Paul', 'Ringo', 'John', 'George']

   b=[ (i+'=[]') for i in my_list]
   for i in b:
        exec(i)
   print(Paul)
```

Use execute function to execute string statement as python statements

Above lines creates four list variables

Comment: There are some things that you can do, but probably shouldn't.

Comment: @jarmod could you mention why not ?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need this type of function, which is not the case here, it’s typically best to avoid any possibility of executing arbitrary and potentially untrusted code. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided. Let’s say at some point in the future the code changes from a static list of Beatles’ names to a list that’s populated from user input - a devious user can now enter malicious Python code, instead of a person’s name, and your program will execute it.

Comment: @jarmod yes i added the code because its a static code and also the user mention to create list not dictionary of list