# Python——Something about exec()

Tags: python, exec

```
def function():
    exec('a=2')
    print(vars())
    print(a)
function()
```

---

```
a=1
def function():
    global a
    exec('a=2')
    print(vars())
function()
print(a)
```

Above: The output was ***{'a': 2}***, but then the error message said ***name 'a' is not defined***.
Below: I still got ***{'a': 2}***, the ***a*** outside was still 1.
Well, what's the difference between ***a = 2*** and ***exec('a = 2')***?

Comment: Check the second and third parameter of [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). Example: `exec('a=2', globals())`

Comment: The solution to nearly every problem with exec is "stop using exec".

Comment: How fool I am! Thanks! @Matthias

Comment: Anything bad with exec()? @khelwood

Comment: [Why should exec and eval be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/3890632)

Comment: I could explain what you had to do to make it work, but I must admint that I never used `exec` in over 15 years of Python programming.

Comment: @Matthias Sounds like exec() is really a trivial function.

Comment: Sounds like I've already had a lot of programming experience and knew which evil language features to avoid. :)