# Error while running counter of how many days ive been alive

Tags: python, windows

```py
print('enter your age')
age = input()

print('this is how many days you have been alive')

time.sleep(1)

print('input the first three letters of the month you were born')

jan = 31
feb = 59
mar = 90
apr = 120
may = 151
jun = 181
jul = 212
aug = 243
sep = 273
oct = 304
nov = 334
dec = 365

month = input()

print('now for the day you were born. put this in number form without any "th"s or "nd"s ')

date = input()

print('your total age is:')

time.sleep(1)

print((int(age) * 365) + int(date) + int(month))
```

the error i get is ValueError: invalid literal for int() for month

I'm a beginner so if you want me to provide more detail let me know, but i believe this is an obvious fix that i just havent thought of yet

when i try removing the int() it gives another error, something like "expected int, got str instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the month values anywhere, you're basically trying to convert   a string to int and it raises an error. Here's a possible fix

```py
month_data = {'jan': 31, 'feb': 91 ...} # this is a dictionary
month = input()
month_data.get(month, None)
if month is None:
    print('invalid month supplied')
else:
    # print age
```

### References:

- [Python dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you accept the month string, but want to use the int value you declared for the particular variable. You can use `eval` to get the value of the particular months variable.

But I guess the more pythonic solution is that of @Ceres using dictionaries.

```
import time

print('enter your age')
age = input()

print('this is how many days you have been alive')

time.sleep(1)

print('input the first three letters of the month you were born')

jan = 31
feb = 59
mar = 90
apr = 120
may = 151
jun = 181
jul = 212
aug = 243
sep = 273
oct = 304
nov = 334
dec = 365

month = input()
month_val = eval(month)

print('now for the day you were born. put this in number form without any "th"s or "nd"s ')

date = input()

print('your total age is:')

time.sleep(1)

print((int(age) * 365) + int(date) + int(month_val))
```

Comment: thanks, this one makes more sense, even though ceres's is probably more efficient, thanks heaps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided