# Flip variable and it's value

Tags: python, variables

I've done some looking on how I can flip a variable name and that variable's value, but I have come up empty-handed.

**What I want**

Let me clarify what I would like with an example.
Imagine I had a variable called `my_variable` and it's value would be a string `'my_new_variable'`

```
my_variable = 'my_new_variable'
```

Is there any way that I can flip these so that it may look like this

```
my_new_variable = 'my_variable'
```

Comment: Your dictionary solution seems plausible; why isn’t it sufficient?

Comment: A dictionary is in fact the perfect way to deal with something like this.  Do you *really* want to have to debug the mess resulting from `my_variable = 'variables'`, or something else that inadvertently references an existing variable in your code?

Comment: I agree that you should look into ways other than using `dict`. That would be far too easy.

Comment: As this seems like an X-Y question, what’s the real problem?

Comment: @barny Yeah, I thought about this. But I'd like a couple of other ways than righting a dictionary. Maybe I might receive one that does not involve using one.

Comment: Would it be best, to answer my own question? Remove `my go` and turn it into an answer?

Comment: [with irony] Yeah I’m with @CaptainTrojan using a dictionary seems far too easy/simple/boring. Let’s all fight against simple solutions.

Comment: I'm feeling a heat of sarcasm coming. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should you want to do that, how about

```py
globals()[my_variable] = 'my_variable'
```

Answer (score 4):

A dict is the appropriate way to do this.  Driving internal symbol names with data is a strong sign of poor program design.  Please use the dict, and refer to [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  External data should drive data relations, but *not* the internal representation.  By doing so, you make your algorithm's structure dependent on the data.  Data manipulation should be independent  of those specific values.

You *can* do it;; a little research on this site will give you the references.  Don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this (after installing `python-varname`):

```
from varname import nameof
my_variable = 'my_new_variable'
exec("%s = '%s'" % (my_variable, nameof(my_variable))
```

Comment: hmm, this could be a solution. [Though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)...

Answer (score 0):

One way this could be done and suggested by almost everyone who has commented is by using a dictionary then flipping the keys and values.

```
variables = {'my_variable':'my_new_variable'}
flipped = {v:k for k,v in variables.items()}
```

output

```
{'my_new_variable': 'my_variable'}
```