# Best way to process JSON into separate lists?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So after receiving JSON with the following code:

```
ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.get('content-type'))
if ctype == 'application/JSON':
    length = int(self.headers.get('content-length'))
    input = JSON.loads(self.rfile.read(length))
```

I received this kind of JSON from print(input) which is a dictionary:

```
{'packageInput': {'dog': [4.18, 0.08, 41.51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'cat': [2.752, 3.69, 2.29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'bird': [4.45, 4.97, 2.37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'chicken': [0.81, 0.61, '0.336', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'min': ['1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '5', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'max': [4, 4, 4, 4, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}
```

As we can see, each "list" in the JSON has "array". How do I extract them into separate python list variable?

such as:

```
dog = []
cat = []
bird = []
chicken = []
```

I have been researching solutions, there are ranging from using `for` loops to modules import. I believe there is a much more simple solution to extract this.

Would you please share an idea?

Comment: Having dynamically named variables is usually a bad idea. You already have something very close which is much better. By doing `variables = data['packageInput']` you can access each list as `data['dog']`, `data['cat']` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments on your question mention, you already have a dictionary which is probably the correct data structure for this. However, if you have a need to pull out a bunch of things from a dict as separate items, [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is a convenient, readable way to do this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

jsn = {'packageInput': {'dog': [4.18, 0.08, 41.51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'cat': [2.752, 3.69, 2.29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'bird': [4.45, 4.97, 2.37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'chicken': [0.81, 0.61, '0.336', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'min': ['1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '5', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'max': [4, 4, 4, 4, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}

dog,cat,bird,chicken = itemgetter('dog','cat','bird','chicken')(jsn['packageInput'])
```

On the other hand, if you are looking for a *dynamic* way to do this — you don't know what variables will be created until you have the json — that's a mistake. It just doesn't work — after all you need to know the variable names later to use them later in the program. Using `print(cat)` later in the program would crash if `"cat"` was not in the json. A dictionary lets you deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

[exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) is what you looking for, but you should **avoid** using it at any cost. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided).

```
d = {'packageInput': {'dog': [4.18, 0.08, 41.51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'cat': [2.752, 3.69, 2.29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'bird': [4.45, 4.97, 2.37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'chicken': [0.81, 0.61, '0.336', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'min': ['1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '5', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'max': [4, 4, 4, 4, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}
obj = d.get('packageInput')
for k in obj.keys():
    exec(f"{k} = {obj.get(k)}")
print(dog)
#[4.18, 0.08, 41.51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Recommended Solution,**
use it as dict which already it is.

```
dog = obj.get('dog')
```