# how to read and execute the scripts in file

Tags: python

This is a simplified example, the python program run on a device and wait for a text file to understand how to execute the next step, the text file will be upload to the device frequently.

How to let the python program "translate" the text file (in this example, `steps.txt` only has one line `"z = x + y"`) into the executable script?

```
import os
import time
x = 3
y = 9
s = None
while 1:
  time.sleep(1)
  try:
    with open("steps.txt", 'r') as f:
        s = f.readline()#s = "z = x + y"
        f.close()
        break
except:
    pass

os.system(s)#'z' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `os.system(s)`, you could use `exec`:

```
exec(s)
```

But note that this is really unsafe, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided).

Comment: thanks, if I have multiple lines in steps.txt, how should I use this?

Comment: I noticed I have to use readlines(), and exec(s[0]), exec(s[1])....., is this same with what you mean?

Comment: @adameye2020 Yeap!

Comment: wondering whether there is a better way for exec line by line, I remember in Matlab I could exec the full scripts in one line

Comment: @adameye2020 You could use `read` instead of `readlines`, than it would be 1 string, or use a for loop, like `for line is s: exec(line)`

Answer (score 4):

As you included in your post, the command prompt returned this error

```
'z' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

when you passed the string `"z = x + y"` into `os.system()`. That is because the command is not run in python. I believe what you were trying to do was

```
# s = "z = x + y"
os.system(f'python -c "{s}"')
```

which would of course return a `NameError`.

Instead, to execute the line of code in your python program, use the `exec()` method, like so:

```
# s = "z = x + y"
exec(s)
```

But be warned! Both [exec() and eval() should **really** be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/13552470), as they pose serious security issues.

*Note: The `f.close()` isn't necessary as you used the `with` statement.*