# How can I turn a string that contains numbers and operators into a result?

Tags: python

I want to convert this string into a result n for the output to be 11.

```
a = "1+5*6/3"
print (a)
```

Comment: You can use the built in function eval() https://towardsdatascience.com/python-eval-built-in-function-601f87db191, but I won't recommend you to use it often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the python `eval` function.

```
a = eval("1+5*6/3")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) built-in function can evaluate a Python expression including any arithmetic expression. But note the `eval()` function is a security concern because it can evaluate any arbitrary Python expression or statement so should be used **only if the input to evaluate is controlled and trusted user input**. There are examples to why eval() is dangerous in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided).

```
a = "1+5*6/3"
result = eval(a)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
11.0
```

**Using ast module as an alternative to eval()**

A safe alternative to *eval()* is using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Recent Python 3 versions disallows passing simple strings to *ast.literal_eval()* as an argument. Now must parse the string to buld an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) then evaluate it against a grammar. This related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68732605/543969) provides an example to evaluate simple arithmetic expressions safely.