# Python how to declare dynamic ( number of arrays )

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dynamic

I want to take integer as input and declare that many arrays with array_names as starting form 0 to that integer
for example :

```
if I give input as 3 , then in my code there should be 
arr1 = [] ,
arr2 = [] ,
arr3 = []
```

I tried this but its giving syntax error

```
arr = []
no_of_arrays = int(input())
for i in range(no_of_arrays):
       arr{i} = []
```

its giving

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use a list instead of a sequence of variables. With `[]` you actually create one. It's not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can technically do this in python using `exec`, it is not recommended.

Instead, you should create a list of lists:

```
arrays = [[] for _ in range(int(input())]
```

Or a dictionary of lists:

```
arrays = {f'arr{i}': [] for i in range(int(input())}
```

Comment: Thanks @Itay Raveh , but why exec is not recommended can you explain ?

Comment: @PranavPatil see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided) post

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to declare primitive variables dynamically.
You can either create a dictionary `d={'Array1':[]....}` or try looking into `exec` function - which is not recommended for many reasons:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    exec('myArr{}=[]'.format(i))
```

Comment: Thanks @OfirY , but why exec is not recommended can you explain ?

Comment: @PranavPatil There are great answers right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable by updating the [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or [locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) dict.

eg:

```
l = locals()
no_of_arrays = int(input())
for i in range(no_of_arrays):
  l[f"arr{i}"] = []

print(arr0)
print(arr1)
```

Comment: Can you please explain for what purpose have you use ``` locals()  ```? Actually I searched for globals and locals , but they related to global and local variables in a function . I am not able to understand the use of locals() in your solution @Shanavas M

Comment: locals() and globals() return the local/global symbol table. Creating a local/global variable will add an entry to local()/global() respectively. Most of the times it works vice versa as well. Add an entry to the locals()/globals() and you get a local/global variable.  Modifying locals/globals is not recommended though.