# Can i make GUI in Python that launches Python code line?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any GUI programs that work like this - click button in GUI and it does launch some python code line or multiple lines, i thought about tkinter, but i found none options to make it launch some python code or is there?
Upd - In terminal code will be too complicated to use the code so i need GUI.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Button can run function with your code. And if you mean `string with code` then it has nothing to do with GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to run python code, the way it is required in the OP -:

1. Using `exec` or `eval` to run python code dynamically(**NOTE:** This would not
   return the output but rather directly run the code as if it were
   normal code.), Also note that [use of `exec` and `eval` should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided) but it had to be mentioned here as a possible way through.

   ```
   exec(object, globals, locals)
   eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])
   ```
2. Launching a terminal window(using [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) method of the os module) and using [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to type and run the
   command that executes given python script, when a button is
   clicked(**NOTE:** With this method as well you will only be able to see
   the output of the script but not fetch it.)

   ```
   # required imports
   import os, pyautogui
   import tkinter as tk
   from tkinter import filedialog

   root = tk.Tk() # initializing the tkinter window.

   def ask_for_running_file(event = None) :
       filetypes = (("python files", '.py'), ("all files","*.*"))
       filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = '/', title = "Select file", filetypes = filetypes) # Get the name of the
   python file to run.

       addr_command = 'start cmd /k "cd "' + filename[ : filename.rindex('/')] # Command used to open the terminal
       run_command = ' python \"' + filename[(filename.rindex('/') + 1) : ] + '\"' # The command to be typed in the terminal using pyautogui to execute the python script.
       os.system(addr_command) # Runs the command required to open the terminal window.
       pyautogui.write(run_command, interval = 0.25) # Writes the command required to execute the python script letter by letter.
   NOTE: The interval here can be adjusted as per use case.
       pyautogui.press('enter') # Pressing enter to execute the run command.
       return

   b1 = tk.Button(root, text = 'run file', command = ask_for_running_file) # The button that open a file dialog to choose
   #which file to run.
   b1.pack() # managing the geometry of the button.

   root.mainloop() # starting mainloop
   ```
3. Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) module to get the output of the execution of a
   terminal command and then display it using tkinter or any other
   module(if required). Note that the subprocess module suggests to use
   the [run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function for most of the use cases so the example provided
   below will involve the use of that only. The documentation lists the use of each and every argument and can be used further to modify the below code as pleased.

   ```
    result = subprocess.run(['python', '\"' + script_name + '\"'],
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True)
   ```

---

Once the way of executing the command is figured out, the button that triggers it and the GUI can be designed in any module as pleased, for example the function shown in method 2 can be used with any other GUI module's button's callback function too! And it should work fine keeping in mind to remove the use of tkinter filedialog within the function rest can stay the same.

---

**NOTE:**

The second method might not always work if there is a disturbance while pyautogui types in the command, and thus it is not suitable for use cases where background processes are needed to achieve the problem's solution.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out when i will be done with my current project!