# import whole list using import once

Tags: python

how do I achieve this,

```
imports = 'tensorflow torch requests re keyword builtins enum sys functools operator os itertools collections'.split()
```

```
import *imports
```

or

```
import imports
```

both fail

Comment: Is this a purely academical question or do you intend to use this in production code?

Comment: Why do you want to import only once? Why not follow standard practice and use multiple import statements?

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange, but you can achieve that by using `exec()`

```
exec(f"import {', '.join(imports)}")
```

Bear in mind that usage of `exec()` with users input is [insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two ways I can point:

1. Using import_module function from importlib, the problem with this method is it will import the module and will store it in as a object, so you can use a variable to get the values, but can't call the module directly in code.

```py
from importlib import import_module
imports = 'tensorflow torch requests re keyword builtins enum sys functools operator os itertools collections'.split()

modules = [import_module(lib) for lib in imports]
```

2. Using exec, it's equivalent to call the imports in your code, and you'll be able to do the call of module functions, classes etc.

```py
imports = 'tensorflow torch requests re keyword builtins enum sys functools operator os itertools collections'.split()

for module in imports:
    exec(f'import {module}')
```