# Creating N dataframes from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create *n* DataFrames using the value *s* as the name of each DataFrame, but I only could create a list full of DataFrames. It's possible to change this list in each of the DataFrames inside it?

```
#estacao has something like [ABc,dfg,hil,...,xyz], and this should be the name of each DataFrame
   estacao = dados.Station.unique()
   for s,i in zip(estacao,range(126)):
     estacao[i] = dados.groupby('Station').get_group(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a dictionary here. Then you can name the keys with `s` and the values can each be the dataframe corresponding to that group:

```py
groups = dados.Station.unique()
groupby_ = datos.groupby('Station')

dataframes = {s: groupby_.get_group(s) for s in groups}
```

Then calling each one by name is as simple as:

```py
group_df = dataframes['group_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **REALLY NEED** to create DataFrames named after `s` (which I named `group` in the following example), using `exec` is the solution.

```py
groups = dados.Station.unique()
groupby_ = dados.groupby('Station')

for group in groups:
    exec(f"{group} = groupby_.get_group('{group:s}')")
```

##### CAVEAT

See this answer to understand why using `exec` and `eval` commands is not always desirable.

**[Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided)**