# split arrays as string in one column of pandas to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have data frame in the below format. The description is in string format.

| file | description |
| --- | --- |
| x | [[array(['MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT'], dtype=object), array([0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217])]] |
| y | [[array(['APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0'], dtype=object), array([0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457])]] |

How can i convert data Frame into below format.

| file | license | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | ['MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT'] | [0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217] |
| y | ['APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0'] | [0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457] |

​Above is just an example. Data frame is very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update,** If elements in the column as string format, you can find array with `regex` formula. *(Note don't use eval, [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided))*

```
import ast
new_cols = lambda x: pd.Series({'licence':ast.literal_eval(x[0]), 
                                'score':ast.literal_eval(x[1])})

df = df.join(df['m'].str.findall(r'\[[^\[\]]*\]').apply(new_cols)).drop('m', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    file    licence                                              score
0   x       ['MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT']                     [0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.6956521...
1   y       ['APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', ...    [0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.2855245...
```

How `regex` formula find arrays: *(find string start with `[` and end with `]` but in finding string should not have `[` or `]` to find all arrays.)*

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\[[^\[\]]*\]', "[[np.array(['MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT'], dtype=object), np.array([0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217])]]",)
["['MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT']",
 '[0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217]']
```

**Old,** You can create new column then join with old `dataframe`.

```
new_cols = lambda x: pd.Series({'licence':x[0][0], 'score':x[0][1]})
df = df.join(df['m'].apply(new_cols)).drop('m', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the description is in string format.

Comment: There are (although few) cases where `eval` may be acceptable, I'd argue that this could be one of those cases, as long as it's clearly known and controlled by OP where the data is coming from~

Comment: @BeRT2me, in you code If in this column user  write as string remove all file from os, your code remove all file from os, because you eval this operation

Comment: @I'mahdi and? If I control the data, it doesn't matter. That's only if there is an outside attack vector possible.

Comment: @I'mahdi thank for your help and time. is there any way i can speed up this for 5 million data.

Comment: @sudojarvis, do you check this, is this slow? 5 million row? or 5 million array in each row?

Comment: @I'mahdi yup i checked it. For 5 million rows.

Comment: @sudojarvis, OK, is this slow? Is this not work for 5 million?

Comment: For small data its working fine.but for 5 million it is still processing.

Comment: @sudojarvis, I recommend you, ask a new question. In new question ask about how find pattern in string in 5 million row in pandas. tag this question with [tag:performance], [tag:optimization]. I know here, Users that help you exist.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
  file                                        description
0    x  [[array(['MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT', 'MIT'], d...
1    y  [[array(['APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', 'APSL-1.0', '...
```

Doing:

```
import ast

df.description = (df.description.str.replace('array', '')
                    .str.replace(', dtype=object', '')
                    .apply(ast.literal_eval))
df[['license', 'score']] = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in df.description.str[0]]
df = df.drop('description', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  file                                            license                                              score
0    x                          [MIT, MIT, MIT, MIT, MIT]  [0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.6956521...
1    y  [APSL-1.0, APSL-1.0, APSL-1.0, APSL-1.0, APSL-...  [0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.2855245...
```