# Execute Python String inside a Python code using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a srting inside my Python code that looks like this:

```
x = "print('Hello World')"
```

I want to execute it as if it is like a seperate .py file. Is there something like

```
execute(x)
```

Comment: You can use `exec()` see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec. Also see this thread for a discussion on the topic, and a comparison of the functions `eval` and `exec`.

Comment: Please have a look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3929826)!

Comment: Why `exec()` should be avoided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided

Comment: Depending on your use case, https://github.com/alexmojaki/python_runner might be good for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exec(x)
```

[See the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

But be careful of injection vulnerabilities: if the string comes from a user, they will have the power to control your computer - e.g. something like `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')` could remove a whole directory.