# Is there any way of using for loop iterator in variable name?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am looking for a way to dynamically use multiple dataframes in a for loop. Any ideas?

I generated 24 dataframes like this ("hour" is 0-23):

```
N = 24

for i in range(int(N)):
    exec("df_hour{} = df_m_a_meaned[df_m_a_meaned['hour']=={}]".format(i, i))`
```

Now I want to use them in a for-loop to generate a plot, I tried this but it obviously isn't working:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Box(
    x="df_hour{}['hour']".format(i),
    y="df_hour{}['priceNum']".format(i), 
    ) for i in range(int(N))])
```

Comment: Have a list or dictionary of the dataframes you want to iterate over? Dynamically creating variable names at run time is usually a bad idea, one that makes code less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't **EVER** use `exec` to generate variables in your normal code, it will only make things harder see [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided), if you want to generate dynamically named variables use a dictionary instead.

```py
my_dataframes = {}
for i in range(int(N)):
    my_dataframes[i] = df_m_a_meaned[df_m_a_meaned['hour']==i]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Box(
    x=my_dataframes[i]['hour'],
    y=my_dataframes[i]['priceNum'], 
    ) for i in range(int(N))])
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Can you explain why using exec makes things harder? I am quite new to python.

Comment: @wolliumm read the following answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided

Comment: @wolliumm Just let me say this: I work with Python since nearly 20 years and I never needed `exec`.