# How to run PHP code from inside a Ruby script?

Tags: php, ruby

I'm trying to come up with a solution to this problem. I have a Ruby script that needs to run some PHP code, but I am new to Ruby, so I don't know how to go about doing this.

```
def run_my_code
    #execute some PHP code here
    # $person = new Person();
    # $person->doSomething();
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related question: [PHP to Ruby compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873857/php-to-ruby-compiler/3886423#3886423)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP to Ruby compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873857/php-to-ruby-compiler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way is to use `exec`

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005968

also `ls` or `cmd` works too  (back tick)

Comment: does it cost much to frequently spawn new processes just to eval a PHP code?

Answer (score 3):

I've heard of [Phuby](http://github.com/tenderlove/phuby), though I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/). It supports [PHP](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.04.html#lang-php) and other languages (Ruby/PHP/C/Java/Scheme/Perl/Javascript).