# how to pull out php code that contain certain words in ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, translation

Say if i have lots of php file (.php) and I'm only want to pull out block of code that contain certain words e.g. $this->te 
Any idea how I do it? using ruby would be better?

```
if ($attachments && count($attachments) > 0) {
 echo "\n\n{$this->te('Attachments')}:\n";
 ...
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?  And what does this really have to do with rails, internationalization or translation? A far simpler solution may be just to use text editor which allows you to do search and replace on all files in a folder.

Comment: the site is actually written in php and it's for translation purpose. What I want to do is actually finding all of the code that got translation in it. Got nothing to do with rails, it's just I am more convinient with ruby so I prefer it in ruby. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873857/php-to-ruby-compiler

Comment: i got lots of php file in which i need to find some code that contain translation on it. got nothing to do with ruby. this is a pure php files. i just need to get those code using ruby thats all.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `grep` for it:

```
grep '$this->te' -R *.php -n
```

If you want to do similar thing with Ruby, you can use something like:

```
Dir.glob('*.php').each do |x|
  File.read(x).split("\n").each_with_index do |line, n|
    puts "Found at #{x}:#{n+1}" if line["$this->te"]
  end
end
```