# Is there any tools to convert perl script to c# code?

Tags: c#, perl

I want to convert a perl application to c#. Is there any tools to convert perl script to c# code?

Comment: Your keyboard? :)

Comment: down vote for what? this is a question.

Comment: Don't know, it doesn't seems to me a bad question. People that downvote should at least explain why if not already explained by some other person.

Comment: This is a bad question it encourages bad habits.  Automatic tools are only good to speed up a process not to avoid tasks you do not understand how to do by hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it not possible to create a practical Perl to Python source code converter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399781/why-is-it-not-possible-to-create-a-practical-perl-to-python-source-code-converte)

Comment: a possible duplicate of course after substituting `Python` for `C#` but the reasons are the same.

Comment: Can I assume C# has some sort of function to call system commands? Then something like system("perl your_perl_script.pl").

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you aware that you can embed a Perl interpreter in other compiled languages, and that you can invoke code from the libraries of other languages within Perl via XS or Inline::...?  For you, Inline::MonoCS lets you run C# code within Perl.

Answer (score 4):

No.  The difference between the class libraries would be very difficult to bridge, even if you were able to do the basic syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are perl .NET compilers I heard.
May be some is commercial, may be some is free, I don't know, but of course I guess they are not too mature.
In the same time they can be useful...

You can compile pieces of your perl code in .NET and then decompile with red gate .NET Reflector or any other good C# decompiler to obtain a C# code.

You cannot do copy and paste but it can help.

Comment: That'll probably be really, really ugly code mind...

Comment: Yes but is an help, not a way to write your code. I use it often when converting bad visual basic code from other people into C# and it helps. Of course it cannot be a copy and paste!

Comment: Seems like it would be faster to just port the code by hand.  It's not that hard if you understand at least the basics of both platforms.